# Regular Expression to find a string included between two characters while EXCLUDING the delimiters

Tags: regex

I need to extract from a string a set of characters which are included between two delimiters, without returning the delimiters themselves.

A simple example should be helpful:

**Target**: extract the substring between square brackets, without returning the brackets themselves.

**Base string**: `This is a test string [more or less]`

If I use the following reg. ex.

```
\[.*?\]
```

The match is `[more or less]`. I need to get only `more or less` (without the brackets).

Is it possible to do it?

Comment: Related: [Regex Match all characters between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6109882)

Answer (score 721, accepted):

Easy done:

```
(?<=\[)(.*?)(?=\])
```

Technically that's using lookaheads and lookbehinds. See [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Width Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). The pattern consists of:

- is preceded by a `[` that is not captured (lookbehind);
- a non-greedy captured group. It's non-greedy to stop at the first `]`; and
- is followed by a `]` that is not captured (lookahead).

Alternatively you can just capture what's between the square brackets:

```
\[(.*?)\]
```

and return the first captured group instead of the entire match.

Comment: "Easy done", LOL! :)
Regular expressions always give me headache, I tend to forget them as soon as I find the ones that solve my problems.

About your solutions: the first works as expected, the second doesn't, it keeps including the brackets. I'm using C#, maybe the RegEx object has its own "flavour" of regex engine...

Comment: It's doing that because you're looking at the whole match rather than the first matched group.

Comment: Does this work if the substring also contains the delimiters? For example in `This is a test string [more [or] less]` would this return `more [or] less` ?

Comment: @gnzlbg no, it would return "more [or"

Comment: This is returning the string along with the begin and end string

Comment: I needed something like this to find where class="border" was used in my code.. but even if preceded or followed by other classes. This helped get me where I needed, thanks!

Comment: `Invalid regular expression: /(?<=[)(.*?)(?=])/: Invalid group`

Comment: @cletus if you have multiple placeholders, how would you get all of them in one shot, or does one have to iterate over the string using this regex?
`while(found = regex.exec("This is a [test] string [more or less]"))`

Comment: Be careful, lookbehinds are not supported by safari, so this can crash your app on safari. https://caniuse.com/?search=lookbehind

Comment: @gnzlbg no it doesn't work for the string `[more [or] less]` check this [demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/7476928f0951).

Comment: @Maxstgt seems to be supported now on Safari (March/2024)

Answer (score 80):

If you are using **JavaScript**, the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1454936/1476885) provided by cletus, `(?<=\[)(.*?)(?=\])` won't work because JavaScript doesn't support the lookbehind operator.

**Edit**: actually, [now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454913/regular-expression-to-find-a-string-included-between-two-characters-while-exclud/32808869?noredirect=1#comment99174096_32808869) (ES2018) it's possible to use the lookbehind operator. Just add **/** to define the regex string, like this:

```
var regex = /(?<=\[)(.*?)(?=\])/;
```

**Old answer**:

Solution:

```
var regex = /\[(.*?)\]/;
var strToMatch = "This is a test string [more or less]";
var matched = regex.exec(strToMatch);
```

It will return:

```
["[more or less]", "more or less"]
```

So, what you need is the second value. Use:

```
var matched = regex.exec(strToMatch)[1];
```

To return:

```
"more or less"
```

Comment: what if there are multiple matches of [more or less] in the string?

Comment: Lookbehind assertions have been [**added to RegExp in ES2018**](http://2ality.com/2017/05/regexp-lookbehind-assertions.html)

Comment: This regex doesn't work for the string `[more [or] less]` check this [demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/7476928f0951).

Answer (score 29):

You just need to 'capture' the bit between the brackets.

```
\[(.*?)\]
```

To capture you put it inside parentheses.  You do not say which language this is using.  In Perl for example, you would access this using the $1 variable.

```
my $string ='This is the match [more or less]';
$string =~ /\[(.*?)\]/;
print "match:$1\n";
```

Other languages will have different mechanisms. C#, for example, uses the [Match collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match%28VS.71%29.aspx) class, I believe.

Comment: Thanks, but this solution didn't work, it keeps including the square brackets. As I wrote in my comment to Cletus' solution, it could be that C# RegEx object interprets it differently. I'm not expert on C# though, so it's just a conjecture, maybe it's just my lack of knowledge. :)

Answer (score 27):

Here's a general example with obvious delimiters (`X` and `Y`):

```
(?<=X)(.*?)(?=Y)
```

Here it's used to find the string between `X` and `Y`. Rubular example [here](https://rubular.com/r/qLh9CqINl5MnaD), or see image:

[image]

Answer (score 19):

`[^\[]` Match any character that is not [.

`+` Match 1 or more of the anything that is not `[`. Creates groups of these matches.

`(?=\])` Positive lookahead `]`. Matches a group ending with `]` without including it in the result.

Done.

```
[^\[]+(?=\])
```

Proof.

http://regexr.com/3gobr

Similar to the solution proposed by null. But the additional `\]` is not required. As an additional note, it appears `\` is not required to escape the `[` after the `^`. For readability, I would leave it in.

Does not work in the situation in which the delimiters are identical. `"more or less"` for example.

Comment: This is a good solution, however I have made a tweak so that it ignores an extra ']' at the end as well: 
`[^\[\]]+(?=\])`

Comment: @SteveEng in case you have `[more [or] less]` it will not match `more [or] less`. check this [demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/81628be2cc1d).

Answer (score 9):

## Most updated solution

If you are using Javascript, the best solution that I came up with is using `match` instead of `exec` method.
Then, iterate matches and remove the delimiters with the result of the first group using `$1`

```
const text = "This is a test string [more or less], [more] and [less]";
const regex = /\[(.*?)\]/gi;
const resultMatchGroup = text.match(regex); // [ '[more or less]', '[more]', '[less]' ]
const desiredRes = resultMatchGroup.map(match => match.replace(regex, "$1"))
console.log("desiredRes", desiredRes); // [ 'more or less', 'more', 'less' ]
```

As you can see, this is useful for multiple delimiters in the text as well

Comment: Which part of your regex is benefiting from that case-insensitivity flag?

Comment: Amazing, you don't need the `/i` flag, also your regex doesn't match `[more [or] less]`. you can see it [here](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/3c75bf505488).

Answer (score 8):

PHP:

```
$string ='This is the match [more or less]';
preg_match('#\[(.*)\]#', $string, $match);
var_dump($match[1]);
```

Answer (score 6):

This one specifically works for javascript's regular expression parser  `/[^[\]]+(?=])/g`

just run this in the console

```
var regex = /[^[\]]+(?=])/g;
var str = "This is a test string [more or less]";
var match = regex.exec(str);
match;
```

Answer (score 5):

To remove also the [] use:

```
\[.+\]
```

Comment: But if you have two sets [] [], there is a problem with this one https://i.imgur.com/NEOLHZk.png

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem using regex with bash scripting.
I used a 2-step solution using pipes with grep -o applying

```
 '\[(.*?)\]'
```

first, then

```
'\b.*\b'
```

Obviously not as efficient at the other answers, but an alternative.

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to find a string between / and #, but # is sometimes optional.  Here is the regex I use:

```
  (?<=\/)([^#]+)(?=#*)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I got without `'['` and `']'` in C#:

```
var text = "This is a test string [more or less]";

// Getting only string between '[' and ']'
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\[(.+?)\]");
var matchGroups = regex.Matches(text);

for (int i = 0; i < matchGroups.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(matchGroups[i].Groups[1]);
}
```

The output is:

```
more or less
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need extract the text without the brackets, you can use bash awk

`echo " [hola mundo] " | awk -F'[][]' '{print $2}'`

result:

`hola mundo`