# Which regex flavors support captures (as opposed to capturing groups)?

Tags: regex, language-agnostic, capture

As I just learned from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651680/grouping-string-by-comma-between-brackets), [.NET regexes can access individual matches within a repeated capturing group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures.aspx).

I. e., if I apply a regex like `\b(\w+\s*)+` to a string of words, only the last word will be stored in `\1` or `Match.Groups(1).Value`, but using `Match.Groups(1).Captures` I get access to all the individual matches the regex iterated over.

Are there other regex flavors that support this besides .NET?

Comment: may be this is the call for Jan Goyvaerts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, only .NET and Perl 6 offer that capability.

Comment: Thanks for Perl 6. Looks like the JGSoft engine is in for a little overhaul. Captures seem to me like a useful feature. I'm still on the fence whether recursive/balanced regexes are a Good Thing or whether they make regular expressions completely unmaintainable.

Comment: I tend to think that if you need recursion *or* intermediate captures, you shouldn't be using regexes at all.  At least, not Perl 5 era regexes; Perl 6 includes major changes to regex syntax, making it easier to use advanced features like those and still be able to read what you've written.

Comment: I've just looked at the Perl 6 regex docs. Wow, that *is* quite a change from Perl 5...