# how to match all group and subgroup in pcre

Tags: c, regex, pcre

a ip or other string, like "11.22.33.44" or "aa.bb.cc.dd". basically, I think it is very easy, `(([\d\w]+)+\.)+[\d\w]+`
but the problem is which group these submatches are in. not like ip, some string is consist of lots of words+separate

in pcre, I don't know how to extract it all words -- "aa bb cc dd ..."

Comment: `\d\w` is redundant - `\w` includes `\d`

Answer (score 1):

You need to do like `(\w+)\.(\w+)\.(\w+)\.(\w+)`

Apparantly, Only [perl6 and .net regex can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652554/which-regex-flavors-support-captures-as-opposed-to-capturing-groups) extract subgroups

<sub>**Note**: `\w` =>`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`</sub>