# how to use one line regular expression to get matched content

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm a newbie to ruby, I want to know if I can use just one line to do the job.

Take the 'search' of this site for example. When user typed `[ruby] regex`, I can use following code to get the tag and keyword

```
'[ruby] regex' =~ /\[(.*?)\](.*)/
tag, keyword = $1, $2
```

Can we write it just in one line?

---

**UPDATE**

Thank you so much! May I make it harder and more interesting, that the input may contains more than one tags, like:

```
[ruby] [regex] [rails] one line
```

Is it possible to use one line code to get the tags array and the keyword? I tried, but failed.

Comment: For the update: If you wanted to do this in a single regular expression, you'd need the .NET or Perl 6 regex engine, currently the only ones that support captures within repeated elements. So with IronRuby, you'd probably have a chance. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652554/which-regex-flavors-support-captures-as-opposed-to-capturing-groups - however, for readability's and maintainability's sake, a two-step approach is probably saner.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You need the `Regexp#match` method.  If you write `/\[(.*?)\](.*)/.match('[ruby] regex')`, this will return a `MatchData` object.  If we call that object `matches`, then, among other things:

- `matches[0]` returns the whole matched string.
- `matches[n]` returns the nth capturing group (`$n`).
- `matches.to_a` returns an array consisting of `matches[0]` through `matches[N]`.
- `matches.captures` returns an array consisting of just the capturing group (`matches[1]` through `matches[N]`).
- `matches.pre_match` returns everything before the matched string.
- `matches.post_match` returns everything after the matched string.

There are more methods, which correspond to other special variables, etc.; you can check [`MatchData`'s docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/MatchData.html) for more.  Thus, in this specific case, all you need to write is

```
tag, keyword = /\[(.*?)\](.*)/.match('[ruby] regex').captures
```

---

**Edit 1:** Alright, for your harder task, you're going to instead want the `String#scan` method, which [@Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090786/how-to-use-one-line-regular-expression-to-get-matched-content/3090808#3090808) used; however, we're going to use a different regex.  The following code should work:

```
# You could inline the regex, but comments would probably be nice.
tag_and_text = / \[([^\]]*)\] # Match a bracket-delimited tag,
                 \s*          # ignore spaces,
                 ([^\[]*) /x  # and match non-tag search text.
input        = '[ruby] [regex] [rails] one line [foo] [bar] baz'
tags, texts  = input.scan(tag_and_text).transpose
```

The `input.scan(tag_and_text)` will return a list of tag–search-text pairs:

```
[ ["ruby", ""], ["regex", ""], ["rails", "one line "]
, ["foo", ""], ["bar", "baz"] ]
```

The `transpose` call flips that, so that you have a pair consisting of a tag list and a search-text list:

```
[["ruby", "regex", "rails", "foo", "bar"], ["", "", "one line ", "", "baz"]]
```

You can then do whatever you want with the results.  I might suggest, for instance

```
search_str = texts.join(' ').strip.gsub(/\s+/, ' ')
```

This will concatenate the search snippets with single spaces, get rid of leading and trailing whitespace, and replace runs of multiple spaces with a single space.

Answer (score 12):

```
'[ruby] regex'.scan(/\[(.*?)\](.*)/)
```

will return

```
[["ruby", " regex"]]
```

you can read more about String#scan here: http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000812 (in short it returns an array of all consecutive matches, the outer array in this case is the array of matches, and the inner is the capture groups of the one match).

to do the assignment you can rewrite it like this (assuming you will only ever have one match in the string):

```
tag, keyword = '[ruby] regex'.scan(/\[(.*?)\](.*)/).flatten
```

depending on exactly what you want to accomplish you may want to change the regex to

```
/^\s*\[(.*?)\]\s*(.+)\s*$/
```

which matches the whole input string, and trims some spaces from the second capture group. Anchoring the pattern to the start and end will make it a bit more efficient, and it will avoid getting false or duplicate matches in some cases (but that very much depends on the input) -- it also guarantees that you can safely use the returned array in assignment, because it will never have more than one match.

As for the follow up question, this is what I would do:

```
def tags_and_keyword(input)
  input.scan(/^\s*\[(.+)\]\s+(.+)\s*$/) do |match|
    tags = match[0].split(/\]\s*\[/)
    line = match[1]
    return tags, line
  end
end

tags, keyword = tags_and_keyword('[ruby] [regex] [rails] one line')
tags # => ["ruby", "regex", "rails"]
keyword # => "one line"
```

it can be rewritten in one line, but I wouldn't:

```
tags, keyword = catch(:match) { input.scan(/^\s*\[(.+)\]\s+(.+)\s*$/) { |match| throw :match, [match[0].split(/\]\s*\[/), match[1]] } }
```

My solution assumes all tags come before the keyword, and that there's only one tags/keyword expression in each input. The first capture globs all tags, but then I split that string, so it's a two-step process (which, as @Tim wrote in his comment, is required unless you have an engine capable of recursive matching).

Answer (score 0):

Put this into your ApplicationHelper or somewhere else you need

```
def element_id_for(f, element)
  matcher   = /id=(".*"|'.*')/
  el_string = f.hidden_field(element.to_sym)
  id_string = matcher.match(el_string)[0].gsub(/id="/, '').chomp('"')
  return    id_string
end
```

Finally, you could use this method like this:

```
form_for :test_form do |f|
  my_id = element_id_for(f, :start_date)
  # => "text_form_start_date"
end
```