# Regular expression string between tags "<string>"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I have a string `"<wpf><xaml><wpf-controls>"`.
I need the string between the tags in array format.
How do I get this?

Comment: You really don't want to parse XML with a regular expression. Use an XML parser like [Nokigiri](http://nokogiri.org/) or some specialised library for XAML. But please, [don't parse XML with regexes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/421705).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex for this problem is really simple it is: `/<(.*?)>/`

For the array part is would reference to the answer on  [how to use one line regular expression to get matched content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090786/how-to-use-one-line-regular-expression-to-get-matched-content)

**EDIT:**
for array of the insides of the tags use `<wpf><xaml><wpf-controls>".scan(/(?:<(.*?)>)*/)`

The `(?: .. )` groups the tag together and the `*` says we want 0 or more of that group :)

Comment: "<wpf><xaml><wpf-controls>".scan(/<(.*?)>/)

i am getting array of arrays, I need only array of strings

Comment: In that case use `<wpf><xaml><wpf-controls>".scan(/(?:<(.*?)>)*/)` the (?: .. ) groups the tag together and the * says we want 0 or more of that group :)

Comment: http://rubular.com/ is a nice way to work your regexes out, you can provide a testtring on which you can try your regex while editing it, great help for understanding whats going on

Comment: I find this answer pretty hard to read, see my answer for a way to do it without making the regex itself more complex.

Answer (score 0):

```
'<wpf><xaml><wpf-controls>'.scan(/<(.*?)>/).map(&:first)
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer ?

Comment: String#scan returns an array of arrays if your regex contains groups. In this case there is exactly one group, so the result array will be [["wpf"],["xaml"],["wpf-controls"]]. So get all the strings from each sub-array via Array#first.
You could also use Array#flatten instead, but my solution would also work if there were multiple groups in the regex.