# What will be the regular expression of the following in python?

Tags: python, regex

I want the regular expression of the following pattern

Rule

1. The pattern should have no no punctuation except `+`. No blank spaces are allowed.Only alphabetical characters are allowed.
2. The patter should be of two or more characters

EDIT:

I am thinking something like:

```
'^\w\w+ |[ \w\w+ + \w\w+] $'
```

But it is not working.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Add details what you tried and what the scenario you are facing this may lead to simpler solution!

Comment: SO is not a code write service, please edit your question and add your code.

Comment: '^\w\w+ |[ \w\w+ + \w\w+] $'

Comment: I am new to regex. Please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can You Use a Single Regular Expression to Parse Function Parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885653/can-you-use-a-single-regular-expression-to-parse-function-parameters)

Comment: Another question, why are you using `^...$` here? Are you trying to match the whole line?

Comment: You want regex to check if string consist of two or more characters. Only word characters and `+` are allowed. Or only letters `a-zA-Z` and `+` ? Strings like `++` are fine?

Comment: Yes, exactly... @bobble bubble

Comment: then `[a-zA-Z+]+` will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question has very limited detail, however the very simple answer is:

```
^[+]{2,}$
```

However, that would only match the character "+" 2 or more times. Since you're saying punctuation, it seems to imply that you want to allow other text. In that case, I would go with:

```
^[\w+ ]{2,}$
```

Which would allow all "word characters" and spaces. In the Python string, you will need to escape the backslash with another backslash.
If you want to experiment with regex strings, I would highly recommend the website http://regex101.com

**EDIT:** I have now seen your updated question, and to only have alphabetical characters and the plus symbol, you will want

```
^[A-Za-z+]{2,}$
```

Comment: You don't have to escape the backslash if you use a raw string `r'^[\w+ ]{2,}$'`