# Multiple regex capture groups using quantifiers

Tags: php, regex

Is there a way to get multiple capture groups out of a regex that is using quantifiers?  For example, say I have this data (simplified from what I have to deal with):

```
<td>Data 1</td>
<td>data 2</td>
<td>data 3</td>
<td>data 4</td>
```

Right now, if I write a regex like this:

```
(?:<td>(.+?)<\/td>\s*){4}
```

I end up with only one capture group, the last one **"data 4"**.  Is there a way to use the quantifier and end up with 4 capture groups, or am I forced to write the regex like this to get what I want:

```
<td>(.+?)<\/td>\s*<td>(.+?)<\/td>\s*<td>(.+?)<\/td>\s*<td>(.+?)<\/td>
```

Yes, I am well aware that I can hack this simple example up much easier programmatically and then apply and necessary regexes or simpler pattern matches.  The data I am working with is far more complex and I would really like to use a regex to handle all of the parsing.

Comment: I guess you missed the last paragraph.  This is a question of "is something possible with a regex", not "whats the best way to parse html".

Comment: I've removed my first comment, but I disagree that the concept here is worth pursuing. Regex is only good for parsing HTML in  *very* simple cases. This isn't such.

Comment: Again, this isn't about parsing HTML, its about whether or not a regex can capture multiple groups using quantifiers.  This is a simple example to illustrate the point.

Comment: Too bad. [Perl 6 and .NET have the capability](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652554/which-regex-flavors-support-captures-as-opposed-to-capturing-groups) to access individual matches in a repeated group, PHP doesn't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With php you can use `preg_match_all` :

```
$str = '<td>Data 1</td>
<td>data 2</td>
<td>data 3</td>
<td>data 4</td>
';
preg_match_all('/(?:<td>(.+?)<\/td>\s*)/', $str, $m);
print_r($m);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <td>Data 1</td>

            [1] => <td>data 2</td>

            [2] => <td>data 3</td>

            [3] => <td>data 4</td>

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Data 1
            [1] => data 2
            [2] => data 3
            [3] => data 4
        )

)
```

Comment: I upvoted this because a more complex version of this is what I am doing already.  It doesn't answer my question about the regex capture groups with quantifiers though.  As I stated in the original content of the question, I would like to avoid programmatic answers to this question and would like to know if its possible from a pure regex perspective.

Comment: @Tony Lukasavage: Thanks. Unfortunatly, as Tim Pietzcker said in a comment, it's not possible in php.