# regex to pull all attributes out of all meta tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, meta-tags

I'm trying to pull meta tags out of a html page, to compare two pages (live and dev) to see if they're SEO is the same after a site redesign/refactor. I need to compare title, meta tags (description, opengraph etc.), h1's, our analytics (Omniture), and our ad tags (doubleclick) are all the same.

My problem is getting meta tags
http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php
only works if they have a name= attribute, same with "mariano at cricava dot com"'s solution.

I don't want to restrict it to having certain attributes, I could make the assumption that all our meta tags have either a name=, or property= or http-equiv= and change the regex appropriately but cannot be entirely sure as it's a massive website and any random crap could be in the tags (hence this tool is to check this stuff!) and would like to leave it as dynamic as possible.

I have

```
$page = @file_get_contents('http://.../');
preg_match_all('#<meta(?:\s+?([^\=]+)\=\"(.+?)\")+?\s*?/?>#sui', $page, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)
```

but the subpatterns override each other, so this only pulls out the last attribute-name=attribute-value pair

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
            [1] => content
            [2] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => <meta name="description" content="some description" />
            [1] => content
            [2] => some description
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
            [1] => content
            [2] => website
        )
...
```

I need all the attributes for all the meta tags. I could do this in two steps, pulling the contents of `<meta ([^>]*)>` then doing a second regular expression on the results, but that seems unnecessary with the power of regex?

Comment: *sigh* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: You're parsing HTML, use a HTML parser.

Comment: To be fair, all the HTML is valid/complete, so it's not arbitrary HTML, we know that it's ok and in a certain format (it's just the key-values I'm unaware of). However - apologies for lodging this question now I can see this has been asked before in different ways - I could use a HTML parser or xlib/DOM/XPath to pull out these details, guess there is a lot more overhead and code but if it's the easiest way, it make sense. But back to the original question, forget it's HTML for now, is there no way to have recurring subpatterns return in preg_match_all rather than just returning the last match?

Comment: You are using a hammer on a screw. It's no surprise that you're pulverising the wood into pulp. You give regexes way more credit than they deserve. Learn yourself some peg. or parser combinators. or parser generators. Or if it's html, just use an html parser.

Comment: I mean, it's understandable that you'd think regexes could do what you want. You've seen them do some fairly sophisticated parsing tasks, and the difference between *those* sophisticated things, and *this* sophisticated thing is hard to grasp without a comp sci professor pounding it into your head over the course of 5 classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But back to the original question, forget it's HTML for now, is there
>   no way to have recurring subpatterns return in preg_match_all rather
>   than just returning the last match?

Not possible with `preg_*`/PCRE (nor any other regex flavor that I know of, but in Perl you could use a `(?{ push @list, $^N })` hack).

Comment: Perl and .NET regexes [do support access to individual repeats of capturing groups](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652554/which-regex-flavors-support-captures-as-opposed-to-capturing-groups).

Answer (score 0):

```
 preg_match_all("<meta\\s*(?:(?:\\b(\\w|-)+\\b\\s*(?:=\\s*(?:[\"\"[^\"\"]*\"\"|'[^']*'|
   [^\"\"'<> ]|[''[^'']*''|\"[^\"]*\"|[^''\"<> ]]]+)\\s*)?)*)/?\\s*>", $content, $meta);
```

try with this

Comment: Even if you *proved* the correctness I wouldn't want this monster in my code. [Trying to parse HTML with regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1184510) is just a mess.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing it this way. First pull out the meta tags with the following regex

```
string regex = "<meta\\s(?:\"[^\"]*\"['\"]*|'[^']*'['\"]*|[^'\">])+>";
```

I found the regex over here -

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/#1736801)

Then pull out attributes using another regex, which would be quite simple to write.