# Regex Match all characters between two strings

Tags: regex

Example:
`This is just\na simple sentence`.

I want to match every character between `This is` and `sentence`. Line breaks should be ignored. I can't figure out the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1049, accepted):

For example

```
(?<=This is)(.*)(?=sentence)
```

[Regexr](http://regexr.com?2tr28)

I used lookbehind `(?<=)` and look ahead `(?=)` so that "This is" and "sentence" is not included in the match, but this is up to your use case, you can also simply write `This is(.*)sentence`.

The important thing here is that you activate the "dotall" mode of your regex engine, so that the `.` is matching the newline. But how you do this depends on your regex engine.

The next thing is if you use `.*` or `.*?`. The first one is greedy and will match till the last "sentence" in your string, the second one is lazy and will match till the next "sentence" in your string.

**Update**

[Regexr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?2tr2n)

```
This is(?s)(.*)sentence
```

Where the (?s) turns on the dotall modifier, making the `.` matching the newline characters.

**Update 2:**

```
(?<=is \()(.*?)(?=\s*\))
```

is matching your example "This is (a simple) sentence". See here on [Regexr](http://regexr.com?2tr5t)

Comment: @tchrist, sorry I had to look this up. Do I understand this correct and `This is(?s)(.*)sentence` would be working?

Comment: @stema: Yes, that should work to enable "dot all" mode under most regex libraries.

Comment: That mostly solved my problem, but how do I include a white space character in my pattern? I tried the following: "(.*?)( \))" to match the " )" at the end of a sequence, but it didn't work.

Comment: @FrEEzE2046 I don't understand, which `)`? If you want to match a bracket you have to escape it, `\)`will match a single closing bracket.

Comment: I'm sorry, what I really want is this: "(.*?=)\("  -  The first ending "(" (opening bracket) of a sequence. The bracket itself shouldn't be included in the match. If it's possible I would also like to ignore each white space character between the bracket and the rest of the match.

Comment: @FrEEzE2046 Is `(.*?)\s*\(` what you mean? `\s` is one whitespace `*` means at least 0 times and `\(` an opening bracket.

Comment: It shouldn't be part of the match. Didn't you write I need to use ?= to do that? Example string: "This is (a simple) sentence". I want to mach "is". I'm able to exclude "This", but I also need to exclude the rest. Currently I'm getting " is (". I'm using the following Regex: @"(?<=This)(?s)(.*?)\s*\("

Comment: I've updated my comment. EDIT: Your last expression did the job. Now, I need to get rid of the remaining white space character between "This" and "(" ... but there could be more than one (I want to exclude all of them.

Comment: Just one note - regexr says now that lookbehind is not supported in javascript

Comment: I want to find including line break and carriage returns ... how to do this..?

Comment: @MohasinAli it's a command switch.  different for each language implementations.  see your lang notes for details.

Comment: I can be wrong but, .* won't work if there is a new line it doesn't include new lines. At least in JS https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-carriage-return

Comment: @Rantiev, you are correct, by default '.' does not match newline characters, but you can change that by using the dotall or singleline mode I mention in my answer. In most languages. But when I remember correctly, you are again correct, not in JavaScript.

Comment: @stema Yep, it works with flag "s" singleline mode /.*/s in js as well.

Comment: This answer looks obsolete. Links mentioned have errors.

Comment: Is there a way to deal with repeated instances of this split in a block of text?  FOr instance: "This is just\na simple sentence.  Here is some additional stuff. This is just\na simple sentence. And here is some more stuff. This is just\na simple sentence. ".  Currently it matches the entire string, rather than each instance.

Comment: I tried this and worked with fixed word, but with my target I got error look-behind requires fixed-width pattern what is equivalent to it with none fixed length (?<=s.*y)target(?=end)

Comment: @MohasinAli to include line break and carriage returns just add the flag `\m`. check this [demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/en/regex-tester/93d77624fe3f).

Answer (score 283):

### Lazy Quantifier Needed

Resurrecting this question because the regex in the accepted answer doesn't seem quite correct to me. Why? Because

```
(?<=This is)(.*)(?=sentence)
```

will match `my first sentence. This is my second` in `This is my first sentence. This is my second sentence.`

[**See demo**](http://regex101.com/r/eZ1gT7/6).

You need a lazy quantifier between the two lookarounds. Adding a `?` makes the star lazy.

This matches what you want:

```
(?<=This is).*?(?=sentence)
```

[See demo](http://regex101.com/r/eZ1gT7/5). I removed the capture group, which was not needed.

**DOTALL Mode to Match Across Line Breaks**

Note that in the demo the "dot matches line breaks mode" (a.k.a.) dot-all is set (see [how to turn on DOTALL in various languages](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-modifiers.html#dotall)). In many regex flavors, you can set it with the online modifier `(?s)`, turning the expression into:

```
(?s)(?<=This is).*?(?=sentence)
```

---

**Reference**

- [The Many Degrees of Regex Greed](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-greed.html)
- [Repetition with Star and Plus](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

Comment: You are correct about the capturing group. Don't know why I have done this. But the difference between `.*` and `.*?` is also explained in my answer (the paragraph before "Update"). So I don't think my answer is incorrect.

Comment: @stema Sorry about the nitpicking, while cruising through some of your answers yesterday that is the only one that made me twitch. :) I softened the first line from `is incorrect` to `doesn't seem quite correct to me`... Hope that doesn't make *you* twitch, probably just a difference of perception about what the regex for such a high-traffic answer should be.

Comment: @zx81 (?<=exclude this).*?(?=and exclude this) this is a fantastic answer thank you. I thought I understand regex but this made me do another read on the subject :) everyday is a learning day :)

Answer (score 80):

Try `This is[\s\S]*?sentence`, works in javascript

Comment: how to perform a lazy lookup in this way?

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo same as above. `[\s\S]*?` (also called: non-greedy wildcard)

Comment: Works in notepad++ also

Answer (score 27):

This:

```
This is (.*?) sentence
```

works in javascript.

Comment: I like the simplicity, but it was not sufficient for me. What I mean is, ```"This is just\na simple sentence".match(/This is (.*?) sentence/)``` returned ```null```. ```"This is just\na simple sentence".match(/This is (.*?) sentence/s)``` returned a helpful result. The difference is the DOTALL ```s``` after the final slash.

Answer (score 19):

use this: `(?<=beginningstringname)(.*\n?)(?=endstringname)`

Comment: Don't know why all the up votes, this allows for 0-1 line breaks, and the line break must be immediately before `endstringname`

Comment: I found it useful to remove the beginning of log lines (timestamp etc). I used new line for the beginning string and "at" for the end string.

Comment: Why have a capture group as opposed to just a match of `.*\n?` (between the lookarounds) and why not just `.*`  ?

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me (I'm using **VS Code**):

for:
`This is just\na simple sentence`

Use:
`This .+ sentence`

Answer (score 5):

In case of  JavaScript you can use `[^]` to [match any character including newlines](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Character_Classes#types).

Using the `/s` flag with a dot `.` to match any character also works, but is applied to the whole pattern and JavaScript does not support [inline modifiers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) to turn on/off the flag.

To match as least as possible characters, you can make the quantifier non greedy by appending a question mark, and use a [capture group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) to extract the part in between.

```
This is([^]*?)sentence
```

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/wnthCl/1).

As a side note, to not match partial words you can use word boundaries like `\bThis` and `sentence\b`

```js
const s = "This is just\na simple sentence";
const regex = /This is([^]*?)sentence/;
const m = s.match(regex);

if (m) {
  console.log(m[1]);
}
```

---

The lookaround variant in JavaScript is `(?<=This is)[^]*?(?=sentence)` and you could check [Lookbehind in JS regular expressions](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind) for the support.

Also see [Important Notes About Lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#limitbehind).

```js
const s = "This is just\na simple sentence";
const regex = /(?<=This is)[^]*?(?=sentence)/;
const m = s.match(regex);

if (m) {
  console.log(m[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use this: `\This is .*? \sentence`

Comment: `#<Inventory:.*? id: nil, batch_code: `

this is my final regex in vscode it extract the `#<Inventory:0x000055c8a2966b60 id: nil, batch_code: "10324"` and leave just the "10324"

Answer (score 3):

RegEx to match everything between two strings using the Java approach.

```
List<String> results = new ArrayList<>(); //For storing results
String example = "Code will save the world";
```

Let's use Pattern and Matcher objects to use RegEx ***(.*?)***.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Code "(.*?)" world");   //java.util.regex.Pattern;
Matcher m = p.matcher(example);                      //java.util.regex.Matcher;
```

Since Matcher might contain more than one match, we need to loop over the results and store it.

```
while(m.find()){   //Loop through all matches
   results.add(m.group()); //Get value and store in collection.
}
```

This example will contain only ***"will save the"*** word, but in the bigger text it will probably find more matches.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is looking for an example of this within a Jenkins context. It parses the build.log and if it finds a match it fails the build with the match.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

node{    
    stage("parse"){
        def file = readFile 'build.log'

        def regex = ~"(?s)(firstStringToUse(.*)secondStringToUse)"
        Matcher match = regex.matcher(file)
        match.find() {
            capturedText = match.group(1)
            error(capturedText)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to deal with repeated instances of this split in a block of text? FOr instance: "This is just\na simple sentence. Here is some additional stuff. This is just\na simple sentence. And here is some more stuff. This is just\na simple sentence. ". to matches each instance instead of the entire string, use below code:

```
data = "This is just\na simple sentence. Here is some additional stuff. This is just\na simple sentence. And here is some more stuff. This is just\na simple sentence."

pattern = re.compile('This is (?s).*? sentence')

for match_instance in re.finditer(pattern, data):
    do_something(match_instance.group())
```

Comment: What if I want to get text between two consecutive This is just\na simple sentence. Patterns?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it:
This was easier for me than trying to figure out the specific regex necessary.

```
int indexPictureData = result.IndexOf("-PictureData:");
int indexIdentity = result.IndexOf("-Identity:");
string returnValue = result.Remove(indexPictureData + 13);
returnValue = returnValue + " [bytecoderemoved] " + result.Remove(0, indexIdentity); `
```

Answer (score 1):

I landed here on my search for regex to convert this print syntax between print "string", in Python2 in old scripts with: print("string"), for Python3. Works well, otherwise use 2to3.py for additional conversions. Here is my solution for others:

Try it out on Regexr.com (doesn't work in NP++ for some reason):

```
find:     (?<=print)( ')(.*)(')
replace: ('$2')
```

for variables:

```
(?<=print)( )(.*)(\n)
('$2')\n
```

for label and variable:

```
(?<=print)( ')(.*)(',)(.*)(\n)
('$2',$4)\n
```

[How to replace all print "string" in Python2 with print("string") for Python3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53917898/how-to-replace-all-print-string-in-python2-with-printstring-for-python3/53917912#53917912)

Answer (score 1):

For python

```
def match_between_strings(text, start_str, end_str):
    pattern = re.escape(start_str) + r'(.*?)' + re.escape(end_str)
    matches = re.findall(pattern, text, re.DOTALL)
    return matches
```

##### Example usage:

```
start_str = "This"
end_str = "sentence"
text = "This is just\na simple sentence"

result = match_between_strings(text, start_str, end_str)
```

##### Result

`[' is just\na simple ']`

Answer (score 1):

Rather than extract the bits you want you could replace the bits you don't want with empty strings.

In Ruby,

```
"This is just\na simple sentence".gsub(/^This is|sentence\z/, '')
  #=> " just\na simple "
```

Answer (score 0):

for a quick search in VIM, you could use 
at Vim Control prompt: /This is.*\_.*sentence

Answer (score 0):

i had this string

```
      headers:
        Date:
          schema:
            type: string
            example: Tue, 23 Aug 2022 11:36:23 GMT
        Content-Type:
          schema:
            type: string
            example: application/json; charset=utf-8
        Transfer-Encoding:
          schema:
            type: string
            example: chunked
        Connection:
          schema:
            type: string
            example: keep-alive
        Content-Encoding:
          schema:
            type: string
            example: gzip
        Vary:
          schema:
            type: string
            example: Accept-Encoding
        Server:
          schema:
            type: number
            example: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
        X-Powered-By:
          schema:
            type: string
            example: ASP.NET
        Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
          schema:
            type: string
            example: '*'
        Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:
          schema:
            type: boolean
            example: 'true'
        Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
          schema:
            type: string
            example: '*'
        Access-Control-Max-Age:
          schema:
            type: string
            example: '-1'
        Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
          schema:
            type: string
            example: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE
        X-Content-Type-Options:
          schema:
            type: string
            example: nosniff
        X-XSS-Protection:
          schema:
            type: string
            example: 1; mode=block
      content:
        application/json:
```

and i wanted to remove everything from the words `headers:` to `content` so I wrote this regex `(headers:)[^]*?(content)`

and it worked as expected finding how many times that expression has occurred.

Answer (score -1):

## Sublime Text 3x

In sublime text, you simply write the two word you are interested in keeping for example in your case it is

"This is" and "sentence"

and you write .* in between

i.e. `This is .* sentence`

and this should do you well

Comment: Not sure the question is about how to do this in Sublime Text but mostly works in Sublime Text. It does not work when there happens to be a linebreak between "This is" and "sentence". Also, sublime text also selects "This is" and "Sentence" rather than only the text _between_ those two strings.