# How to get a method name which has specific attribute using regex

Tags: c#, regex

Help needed in parsing method name which has specific attribute.

Rules:
1) All the methods attributed with minimum '[Test' should be listed.
2) methodName will have a space character before the name and '(' symbol at the end of the name. Most likely next line to the Test attribute or on the second line.

Sample 1:

```
[Test]
public Type methodName(parametes ...)
```

Sample 2:

```
//[Test]
public Type methodName(parametes ...)
```

Sample 3:

```
[Test (, some names etc)]
public Type methodName(parametes ...)
```

Sample 4:

```
[Test (, some names etc)]
[Other optional attributes]
public Type methodName(parametes ...)
```

Expected Result: **methodName**

I tried couple of suggestions like this [Regex Match all characters between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109882/regex-match-all-characters-between-two-strings). But, not successful.

Comment: Why do you want to use Regex?

Comment: You should be using Reflection to have the work done for you.

Comment: I was given list of files, each file has classes with names different from the file name. I felt regex would be more opt n less manual in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Not so fancy with all the regex stuff, but it works, with the sample cases....

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\temp\samples.txt");

var matched = false;
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    if(matched)
    {
        var match = Regex.Match(line, @"public");
        if(match.Length > 0)
        {
            matched = false;
            match = Regex.Match(line, @"[a-zA-Z_]+( )?(?=\()"); 
            Console.WriteLine (match.Value);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        matched = Regex.IsMatch(line, @"\[.*Test.*\]");
    }
}
```

Or you could run all the files with the unit runner and it will list all the names of the tests....