# RichTextBox selective syntax highlighting

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, syntax-highlighting

I have this code to apply basic syntax highlighting to a RichTextBox

```
    public Regex _KeyWords = new Regex ("event|explicit|extern|false|finally|fixed|float|for");

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int _SelPos = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
        foreach (Match keyWordMatch in _KeyWords.Matches(richTextBox1.Text))
        {
            richTextBox1.Select(keyWordMatch.Index, keyWordMatch.Length);
            richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
            richTextBox1.SelectionStart = _SelPos;
            richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
        }
    }
```

It works fine, but i can't find a way to highlight **only** the text contained between two tags, for example:

```
<tagStart>
public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
}
<tagEnd>
```

I think it can be done with **Regex** but i don't have that much experience with it, so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should work.

```
(?<=<tagStart>)(.*)(?=<tagEnd>)
```

[GSkinner example](http://regexr.com?35tul)

[Credit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109882/regex-match-all-characters-between-two-strings)

Comment: @Adrao Updated with new GSkinner link. Works on there, what do you mean?