# How to find the strings between $ and /$ using Regex

Tags: c#, .net, text-parsing

I have a string like this

```
ABCD$-$ToBeFetched1/$-$ToBeFetched2/$-EF$GH
```

How do I retrieve the string between `$` and `/$`?

Expected string should be

1. `ToBeFetched1`
2. `ToBeFetched2`

Comment: Welcome to SO.  http://whathaveyoutried.com? Please show us what you have so far. SO is not a code writing service, and you will get a better response if you provide evidence of your own work. Please see [the Help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Tried with this \$([^$]*)\ /$

Comment: update your question with what you have tried. You are almost there. Maybe you can try : \$([^$]*)\/\$

Comment: Please clarify: do you want specifically a Regex-based solution? Or are you interested in some specific programming language or processing tool?

Comment: @LuisFilipe: I've just rolled it back. The .Net context is relevant as Regex engines/dialects are different between platforms.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex Match all characters between two strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109882/regex-match-all-characters-between-two-strings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Regex r = new Regex(Regex.Escape("-$") + "(.*?)"  + Regex.Escape(@"/$"));
                MatchCollection matches = r.Matches("ABCD$-$ToBeFetched1/$-$ToBeFetched2/$-EF$GH");
            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
            }
```

Here this will work for sure.

Comment: provided that the input does not start with a `$data/$` group without a `-` sign

Answer (score 2):

Since you have "open" and "close" markers, the regex expression would obviously be built around this form:

```
[head-marker: $] [the content you are interested in: anything] [tail-marker: /$]
```

so, with addition of a parentheses to form a capturing group:

```
$(.*)$
```

However, two problems here: `*` expressions are greedy (and you dont want it to be, as you want all smallest matches possible) - so it has to be weakened, and also the `$` is a special character in regex, so it has to be escaped:

```
\$(.*?)/\$
```

this forms almost-good expression. It will however falsely match agains such input:

```
aaaaa/$bbbbb/$ccccc    ->    bbbbb
```

because the "head-marker" can skip the slash and hit the first dollar sign what most probably you wouldn't want. Hence, some lookbehind would be useful here too:

```
(?!</)\$(.*?)/\$
```

The `?!<XXXX` instructs to match only if XXXX does not **precede** the potential match.

See also [MSDN: Regex syntax and operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx)

edit: actually Arie's suggestion is much simplier as it doesn't use capturing group. Note the small difference though: Arie's example explicitely fobids the data to contain a dollar sign, so `ABCD$-$ToBeFe$tched1/$-` will result in `tched1` not `ToBeFe$tched1`. If you need the latter, just change the inner `[^$]` part. Think and pick what you actually need!

Answer (score 1):

Using String Methods:

```
string s ="ABCD$-$ToBeFetched1/$-$ToBeFetched2/$-EF$GH";

var results = s.Split('-')
               .Where(x=> x.StartsWith("$") && x.EndsWith("/$"))
               .Select(y=> y.Substring(1,y.Length - 3));

//Console.WriteLine("string1: {0}, string2:{1}",results.ToArray());
```

Comment: Indeed! I've just rolled it back. The .Net context is relevant as Regex engines/dialects are different between platforms.

Answer (score 1):

> (?<=\$)[^$]{1,}(?=/\$)

**(?<=\$)** - positive lookbehind: it ensurers your match starts right after **$** (**$** not included in the match)

**[^$]{1,}** - matches characters other than **$**; **{1,}** instead of ***** to ensure there will be no empty matches (for strings lilke "**$/$**")

**(?=/\$)** - positive lookahead: it ensures your match ends right before **/$** (**/$** not included in the match)