# Regular expression to find specific text within a string enclosed in two strings, but not the entire string

Tags: regex

I have this type of text:

```
string1_dog_bit_johny_bit_string2
string1_cat_bit_johny_bit_string2
string1_crocodile_bit_johny_bit_string2
string3_crocodile_bit_johny_bit_string4
string4_crocodile_bit_johny_bit_string5
```

I want to find all occurrences of “bit” that occur only between string1 and string2. How do I do this with regex?

I found the question [Regex Match all characters between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109882/regex-match-all-characters-between-two-strings), but the regex there matches the entire string between string1 and string2, whereas I want to match just parts of that string.

I am doing a global replacement in Notepad++. I just need regex, code will not work.

Thank you in advance.

Roman

Comment: you could capture "bit" in a group like this: (?<=string1).*(bit).*(?=string2)

Comment: In which language or tool do you want this?

Comment: I need this in Notepad++.

Comment: Thank you. (?<=string1).*(bit).*(?=string2) finds the entire string between string1 and string2. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

This regex will do the job:

```
^string1_(?:.*(bit))+.*_string2$
```

- `^` means the start of the text (or line if you use the `m` option like so: `/<regex>/m` )
- `$` means the end of the text
- `.` means any character
- `*` means the previous character/expression is repeated 0 or more times
- `(?:<stuff>)` means a non-capturing group (`<stuff>` won't be captured as a result of the matching)

Comment: he needs all occurrences

Comment: Thank you. This one matches the entire string, including string1 and string 2.

Comment: `bit` is captured in the group `\1`, that's how regex work :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `^string1_(.*(bit).*)*_string2$` if you don't care about performance or don't have large/many strings to check. The outer parenthesis allow multiple occurences of "bit".

If you provide us with the language you want to use, we could give more specific solutions.

**edit:** As you added that you're trying a replacement in Notepad++ I propose the following:
Use `(?<=string1_)(.*)bit(.*)(?=_string2)` as regex and `$1xyz$2` as replacement pattern (replace xyz with your string). Then perform an "replace all" operation until N++ doesn't find any more matches. The problem here is that this regex will only match 1 `bit` per line per iteration - and therefore needs to be applied repeatedly.

Btw. even if a regexp matches the whole line, you can still only replace parts of it using capturing groups.

Comment: Thank you. This one finвы the whole line instead of just “bit”

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly here a code to do what you want

```
            var intput = new List<string>
            {
                "string1_dog_bit_johny_bit_string2",
                "string1_cat_bit_johny_bit_string2",
                "string1_crocodile_bit_johny_bit_string2",
                "string3_crocodile_bit_johny_bit_string4",
                "string4_crocodile_bit_johny_bit_string5"
            };
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<bitGroup>bit)");
        var allMatches = new List<string>();
        foreach (var str in intput)
        {
            if (str.StartsWith("string1") && str.EndsWith("string2"))
            {
                var matchCollection = regex.Matches(str);
                allMatches.AddRange(matchCollection.Cast<Match>().Select(match => match.Groups["bitGroup"].Value));
            }
        }


        Console.WriteLine("All matches {0}", allMatches.Count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex:

```
(?:string1|\G)(?:(?!string2).)*?\Kbit
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/sU3gC3). Tried it on notepad++ as well and it's working.

There're description in the demo site, but if you want more explanations, let me know and I'll elaborate!