# Regexp all characters between CompileC and -o

Tags: objective-c, regex, clang, xcodebuild, nsregularexpression

I need extract compile flags from `xcodebuild` output,
So I want to get characters between `"CompileC"` and `"-o"`

I tried to do as in question described
[Regex Match all characters between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109882/regex-match-all-characters-between-two-strings)

I am using NSRegularExpression

```
CompileC.*?\-o  (match nothing)

CompileC.*?\-   (give characters between CompileC and first "-", but I need "-o")
```

it does not work, I had tried other versions, but i did not achieve good result.

How can I do that? what regexp should I use?

**Update:**

now works with `NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators`!

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"CompileC.*?\-o "
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators
                                                                         error:&regexError];
```

Comment: @Sniffer, thanks, you could add the answer, and I can accept it )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CompileC.*?\-o` should work. Make sure the dot can match newlines by activating this option in your regular expression constructor.