# How to extract a part of the url through regular expression in textwrangler?

Tags: regex, textwrangler

My work involves manipulating lots of data. I use textwrangler as text editor but I guess the things would remain the same on all text editors.

So I have a url

```
 http://example.com/swatches/frisk-watches/pr?p[]=sort%3Dpopularity&sid=812%2Cf13&offer=GsdOfferOnWatches07.&ref=4c83d65f-bfaf-4db6-b5f5-d733d7b1d2af
```

The above one is a sample url

I want to capture the text GsdOfferOnWatches07. i.e text from offer= and till &ref using regular expression on textwragler Ctrl+F feature.

How can I do that?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109882/regex-match-all-characters-between-two-strings

Comment: Also, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @VusP Context is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$link = 'http://example.com/swatches/frisk-watches/pr?p[]=sort%3Dpopularity&sid=812%2Cf13&offer=GsdOfferOnWatches07.&ref=4c83d65f-bfaf-4db6-b5f5-d733d7b1d2af';

preg_match('/offer=(.*?)&ref/', $link, $match);      
echo $match[1];'
```

Comment: yes the above script is written in php. I didn't notice that your questions was not php related. But you can adopt the regex for your app.

Comment: Please tell me how to do that this kind of manipulation in the context of a text editor

Comment: Try to use this regex: `offer=(.*?)&ref`