# Regex comparison in PowerShell returns two matches instead of one

Tags: regex, powershell

I have tab delimited data in an array and applying the regex match as shown below i am able to get the id value as required.

However the `$matches` variable returns two values and they are the same value.

```
$data = @(
            'name1  "1001"  role1',
            'name2  "1002"  role2'
        )

foreach($d in $data)
{
    $d -match '(?<=")(.*)(?=")' | out-null #search for id in quotes
    $id = $matches[0]
    #...  
}
```

When I check `$matches` I get 2 same matches instead of 1 -

```
PS C:\> $matches

Name                           Value                                           
----                           -----                                           
1                              1002                                            
0                              1002
```

I am a regex beginner. I got the regex string to apply from here ([Regex Match all characters between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109882/regex-match-all-characters-between-two-strings)).

So I either need to tweak my regex logic or there is a reason why `$matches` returns two same values for a single match. I tried searching for a relevant answer but was not able to find an article to explain this. Can someone please advice on what is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `$matches[0]` you find the complete match

In `$matches[1]` you find the content of the first [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

==> You don't need a capturing group around the whole pattern, so just remove the brackets

```
'(?<=").*(?=")'
```

Comment: Aha! So it was a regex tweak! Thanks for the reference link. While i am still trying to understand how a capturing group works, i am glad to see just 1 match as expected.