# Regular expression to match everything at beginning and end

Tags: regex

This question is a little confusing. I want to match everything in between the things I am searching for including the string I am using to search. For example, I have this list:

1. This is a sentence
2. This is a fake
3. This can be a sentence

I want it to match the entire line. For this case I want it to match This and sentence, so it returns This is a sentence and This can be a sentence. I have tried something like this: [Regex Match all characters between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109882/regex-match-all-characters-between-two-strings). That does not work because it does not take the original keywords. It would only take the matched string BETWEEN the keywords.

How can this be accomplished?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the expression `"This.*sentence"` will give you everything. That is, it matches `This`, then all characters, then `sentence`. If either `This` or `sentence` is missing, then it won't match.

Comment: @irule311: My bad. I didn't need to escape the period. Without it, the sample works.

Answer (score 0):

^This.*sentence$

I think this should work.

If you want to extract, then you use the parenthesis.

The ^ notes the beginning of the line and the $ marks the end.
^This matches This at the start of the line.
sentence$ matches sentence as the last word at the end of the line.

Comment: $ echo "This is a sentence" | grep ^This.*sentence$  
This is a sentence  

$ echo "This is a sentenceaa" | grep ^This.*sentence$  

$ echo "This is a fake" | grep ^This.*sentence$  

$ echo "This can be a sentence" | grep ^This.*sentence$  
This can be a sentence

Comment: What does that mean? I've found that removing the "$" does the job, but only for the first line.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/eEGp070P

The formatting in my response is messed up so it looks like one long line.  Apparently, the response could only be edited for 5 minutes and the time expired.  Look at the output of the pastebin link.

The regex looks fine to me.

Comment: Anthony: Comments don't let you do any fancy formatting. You could edit your answer to add the information from your comment. It would be good information to show that your regex does indeed work.

Comment: I don't understand how this works. It does not match in regexr when I test it.