# regex to catch every thing between occurrences of a word

Tags: regex

I want a regex to catch everything inside occurrences of a specific word say `hello`.
left inclusive and right exclusive.
`hello all everything hello eve` will give `hello all everything` and `hello eve`.

I am using `hello.*(?=hello)` using reference from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109882/regex-match-all-characters-between-two-strings), see  [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uT3vA4/2). But it only match once and i tried some possibility no luck. Is it possible?

input:

```
hello i am xyz lol hello i
am abc ..;sda<>
hello
i am pqr ahe kiop hello
abc axyz
no
yes 
hepdd
jol
hello
podjkd
dasfh
```

output expected:

```
1:hello i am xyz lol

2:hello i
am abc ..;sda<>

3:hello
i am pqr ahe kiop

4:hello
abc axyz
no
yes 
hepdd
jol

5:hello
podjkd
dasfh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `s` (DOTALL) flag with this regex:

```
/(hello.*?)(?=hello|\z)/gmsi
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pZ8jL7/3)

- `\z` will match last character in multiline text.
- `s` will match newline as well while using `.*?`
- Use `.*?` for non-greedy regex

Comment: that's seems right. one last think, can you please confirm that it will work in  java Pattern and Matcher .?

Comment: Yes it will definitely work in Java. Just make sure to use `DOTALL` flag in Java using `Pattern.DOTALL` (2nd parameter in `Pattern.compile` call)