# Swift Get string between 2 strings in a string

Tags: ios, string, swift, substring

I am getting a string from html parse that is;

```
string = "javascript:getInfo(1,'Info/99/something', 'City Hall',1, 99);"
```

my code is something like

```
var startIndex = text.rangeOfString("'")
var endIndex = text.rangeOfString("',")
var range2 = startIndex2...endIndex
substr= string.substringWithRange(range)
```

i am not sure if my second splitting string should be "'" or "',"

i want my outcome as

```
substr = "Info/99/something"
```

Comment: Is there always the same length (for example the 1) - or is that different? Is the 'Info/..." always the same? Pls share some more Strings, to find out the best way to get the String.

Comment: javascript:getInfo(1,'Info/123/somethingelse', 'City2 hall3',456,789);

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I'd use a regular expression to extract substrings from complex input like this.

Swift 3.1:

```swift
let test = "javascript:getInfo(1,'Info/99/something', 'City Hall',1, 99);"

if let match = test.range(of: "(?<=')[^']+", options: .regularExpression) {
    print(test.substring(with: match))
}

// Prints: Info/99/something
```

Swift 2.0:

```swift
let test = "javascript:getInfo(1,'Info/99/something', 'City Hall',1, 99);"

if let match = test.rangeOfString("(?<=')[^']+", options: .RegularExpressionSearch) {
    print(test.substringWithRange(match))
}

// Prints: Info/99/something
```

Comment: For more detail on the regex, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109882/regex-match-all-characters-between-two-strings

Answer (score 134):

```
extension String {
    
    func slice(from: String, to: String) -> String? {
        return (range(of: from)?.upperBound).flatMap { substringFrom in
            (range(of: to, range: substringFrom..<endIndex)?.lowerBound).map { substringTo in
                String(self[substringFrom..<substringTo])
            }
        }
    }
}

"javascript:getInfo(1,'Info/99/something', 'City Hall',1, 99);"
  .sliceFrom("'", to: "',")
```

Comment: @oisdk does it work if we need to slice from a string to the end of the string ? Ex : "blabla popo titi toto" -> slice(from "popo", to : endOfString) ?

Comment: In Swift 4 you can also compute the second range as `self[substringFrom...].range(of: to)`, that saves some keystrokes and the mention of `endIndex`.

Comment: I found this `return flatmap.().map()` code pretty hard to grok for the function; so I tried [rewriting a version using `guard`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57865482/1265393).

Comment: @Makaille see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69242560/7486818)

Answer (score 31):

I rewrote [one of the top Swift answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31727051/1265393) to understand what it was doing with `map`. I prefer a version using `guard`, IMO.

```swift
extension String {
    
    func slice(from: String, to: String) -> String? {
        guard let rangeFrom = range(of: from)?.upperBound else { return nil }
        guard let rangeTo = self[rangeFrom...].range(of: to)?.lowerBound else { return nil }
        return String(self[rangeFrom..<rangeTo])
    }
    
}
```

behavior:

```
let test1 =   "a[b]c".slice(from: "[", to: "]") // "b"
let test2 =     "abc".slice(from: "[", to: "]") // nil
let test3 =   "a]b[c".slice(from: "[", to: "]") // nil
let test4 = "[a[b]c]".slice(from: "[", to: "]") // "a[b"
```

Answer (score 15):

To find all substrings that are between a starting string and an ending string:

```
extension String {
    func sliceMultipleTimes(from: String, to: String) -> [String] {
        components(separatedBy: from).dropFirst().compactMap { sub in
            (sub.range(of: to)?.lowerBound).flatMap { endRange in
                String(sub[sub.startIndex ..< endRange])
            }
        }
    }
}

let str = "start A end ... start B end"
str.sliceMultipleTimes(from: "start", to: "end")    // ["A", "B"]
```

Comment: Hi, I love this answer, how can we slightly change the returned results to be the string  between the 2 strings but also include the from and to not just return what's in between? Thanks.

Comment: @Wael Just change the last line to: from + String(sub[sub.startIndex ..< endRange]) + to

Comment: Thank you. I did work it out Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 6):

This works if it is always the second split:

```
let subString = split(string, isSeparator: "'")[1]
```

Comment: let subString = split(text, "'") ; return subString[1]; in this code it gives error "Missing argument for parameter "isSeparator" in call"

Answer (score 6):

In Swift 4 or later you can create an extension method on StringProtocol to support substrings as well. You can just return a `Substring` instead of a new String:

edit/update: **Swift 5 or later**

```
extension StringProtocol  {
    func substring<S: StringProtocol>(from start: S, options: String.CompareOptions = []) -> SubSequence? {
        guard let lower = range(of: start, options: options)?.upperBound
        else { return nil }
        return self[lower...]
    }
    func substring<S: StringProtocol>(through end: S, options: String.CompareOptions = []) -> SubSequence? {
        guard let upper = range(of: end, options: options)?.upperBound
        else { return nil }
        return self[..<upper]
    }
    func substring<S: StringProtocol>(upTo end: S, options: String.CompareOptions = []) -> SubSequence? {
        guard let upper = range(of: end, options: options)?.lowerBound
        else { return nil }
        return self[..<upper]
    }
    func substring<S: StringProtocol, T: StringProtocol>(from start: S, upTo end: T, options: String.CompareOptions = []) -> SubSequence? {
        guard let lower = range(of: start, options: options)?.upperBound,
            let upper = self[lower...].range(of: end, options: options)?.lowerBound
        else { return nil }
        return self[lower..<upper]
    }
    func substring<S: StringProtocol, T: StringProtocol>(from start: S, through end: T, options: String.CompareOptions = []) -> SubSequence? {
        guard let lower = range(of: start, options: options)?.upperBound,
            let upper = self[lower...].range(of: end, options: options)?.upperBound
        else { return nil }
        return self[lower..<upper]
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
let string = "javascript:getInfo(1,'Info/99/something', 'City Hall',1, 99);"
let substr = string.substring(from: "'")                   // "Info/99/something', 'City Hall',1, 99);"
let through = string.substring(through: "Info")  // "javascript:getInfo"
let upTo = string.substring(upTo: "Info")  // "javascript:get"
let fromUpTo = string.substring(from: "'", upTo: "',")  // "Info/99/something"
let fromThrough = string.substring(from: "'", through: "',")  // "Info/99/something',"

let fromUpToCaseInsensitive = string.substring(from: "'info/", upTo: "/something", options: .caseInsensitive)  // "99"
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `var arr = str.componentsSeparatedByString(",")` as your second split which will return you array

Comment: im doing this substring process in a a function, when i call return  subString[1]
gives error "cannot subscript a value of type '[String]' with an index of type ()."  if i call subString[0] it works as expected

Answer (score 5):

Swift 4.2:

```
extension String {

    //right is the first encountered string after left
    func between(_ left: String, _ right: String) -> String? {
        guard let leftRange = range(of: left), let rightRange = range(of: right, options: .backwards)
            ,leftRange.upperBound <= rightRange.lowerBound else { return nil }

        let sub = self[leftRange.upperBound...]
        let closestToLeftRange = sub.range(of: right)!
        return String(sub[..<closestToLeftRange.lowerBound])
    }

}
```

Comment: Remove `options: .backwards` if you want `[a[b]c]` to return `a[b` instead of `a[b]c`

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 5**

```
extension String {
    /// Returns an array of substrings between the specified left and right strings.
    /// Returns an empty array when there are no matches.
    func substring(from left: String, to right: String) -> [String] {
        // Escape special characters in the left and right strings for use in a regular expression
        let leftEscaped = NSRegularExpression.escapedPattern(for: left)
        let rightEscaped = NSRegularExpression.escapedPattern(for: right)

        // Create a regular expression pattern to match content between the last occurrence of the left string
        // and the right string
        let pattern = "\(leftEscaped).*(?<=\(leftEscaped))(.*?)(?=\(rightEscaped))"

        // Create a regular expression object with the pattern
        guard let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: []) else {
            return []
        }

        // Find matches in the current string
        let matches = regex.matches(in: self, options: [], range: NSRange(startIndex..., in: self))

        // Extract the substrings from the matches and return them in an array
        return matches.compactMap { match in
            guard let range = Range(match.range(at: 1), in: self) else { return nil }
            return String(self[range])
        }
    }
}

// Example usage
let result = "cat cat dog rat".substring(from: "cat", to: "rat")
print(result) // Output: [" dog "]
```

Answer (score 4):

Consider using a regular expression to match everything between single quotes.

```
let string = "javascript:getInfo(1,'Info/99/something', 'City Hall',1, 99);"

let pattern = "'(.+?)'"
let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: nil, error: nil)
let results = regex!.matchesInString(string, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, count(string)))  as! [NSTextCheckingResult]

let nsstring = string as NSString
let matches = results.map { result in return nsstring.substringWithRange(result.range)}

// First match
println(matches[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to support also from the start or end of the string

```
extension String {
    func slice(from: String, to: String) -> String? {
        return (from.isEmpty ? startIndex..<startIndex : range(of: from)).flatMap { fromRange in
            (to.isEmpty ? endIndex..<endIndex : range(of: to, range: fromRange.upperBound..<endIndex)).map({ toRange in
                String(self[fromRange.upperBound..<toRange.lowerBound])
            })
        }
    }
}

"javascript:getInfo(1,'Info/99/something', 'City Hall',1, 99);"
  .slice(from: "'", to: "',") // "Info/99/something"

"javascript:getInfo(1,'Info/99/something', 'City Hall',1, 99);"
  .slice(from: "", to: ":") // "javascript"

"javascript:getInfo(1,'Info/99/something', 'City Hall',1, 99);"
  .slice(from: ":", to: "") // "getInfo(1,'Info/99/something', 'City Hall',1, 99);"

"javascript:getInfo(1,'Info/99/something', 'City Hall',1, 99);"
  .slice(from: "", to: "") // "javascript:getInfo(1,'Info/99/something', 'City Hall',1, 99);"
```

---

if you want another syntax, maybe more readable

```
extension String {
    func slice(from: String, to: String) -> String? {
        guard let fromRange = from.isEmpty ? startIndex..<startIndex : range(of: from) else { return nil }
        guard let toRange = to.isEmpty ? endIndex..<endIndex : range(of: to, range: fromRange.upperBound..<endIndex) else { return nil }
        
        return String(self[fromRange.upperBound..<toRange.lowerBound])
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4 version of @litso. To find all values in text

```
func find(inText text: String, pattern: String) -> [String]? {
    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: .caseInsensitive)
        let result = regex.matches(in: text, options: .init(rawValue: 0), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: text.count))

        let matches = result.map { result in
            return (text as NSString).substring(with: result.range)
        }

        return matches
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
    return nil
}
```