# Is it possible find the string between two strings?

Tags: iphone, swift, swift3

I tried to phase a html, i wanted to get the String in the div class like

```
    <div class = "ContentGrid"> xxxxxxxx     </div> 
....some content
    <div class = "ContentGrid"> xxxxxxxx     </div> 
....some content
    <div class = "ContentGrid"> xxxxxxxx     </div>
```

is it possible store all the string xxxxxxxx   in ContentGrid in a array? thanks a lot

Comment: What does "phase a html" mean? Do you mean parse an HTML page? You should use a library like [Fuzi](https://github.com/cezheng/Fuzi) for that.

Comment: @EricAya, yes, just a typo, thanks for your suggestion, i will try it later.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift Get string between 2 strings in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31725424/swift-get-string-between-2-strings-in-a-string)