# How to extract multiline string between "---" in Swift

Tags: regex, swift, linux, text-processing

I want to extract a YAML block from a string. This block is not of typical YAML, and starts and ends with `---`. I want the text in between these markers without the markers themselves. Below is a testing string (swift 4):

```swift
let testMe = """
--- 
# Metadata
title: hum
author: jecatatu
email: jecatatu@gmail.com
---
This is more text outside the yaml block
"""
```

In pure regex the pattern would be `---([\s\S]*?)---`. My initial thought, since I am a beginner was to use [VerbalExpressions](https://github.com/VerbalExpressions/SwiftVerbalExpressions), but I couldn't reproduce this pattern using Verbal Expression. The closest I got was:

```swift
let tester = VerEx()
    .find("---")
    .anything()
    .find("---")
```

How do I extract anything in between (but without) --- from a string using regex in Swift?

Comment: Possible duplicate of Swift [Get string between 2 strings in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31725424/swift-get-string-between-2-strings-in-a-string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use String method

```
func range<T>(of aString: T, options mask: String.CompareOptions = default, range searchRange: Range<String.Index>? = default, locale: Locale? = default) -> Range<String.Index>? where T : StringProtocol
```

and use the regex pattern to find all characters between two strings from this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23756210/2303865):

```
let testMe = """
---
# Metadata
title: hum
author: jecatatu
email: jecatatu@gmail.com
---
This is more text outside the yaml block
"""

let pattern = "(?s)(?<=---\n).*(?=\n---)"
if let range = testMe.range(of: pattern, options: .regularExpression) {
    let text = String(testMe[range])
    print(text)
}
```

---

```
# Metadata
title: hum
author: jecatatu
email: jecatatu@gmail.com
```

Comment: Note that the result *includes* the newline after the first separator.

Comment: @MartinR yes I din't think about taking care of the newline. Regex updated to just get the lines in between.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex :

```
let regex = "(?s)(?<=---).*(?=---)"
```

Thanks to @leo that shows the correct regex in the accepted answer

And then with this function you can evaluate it:

```
 func matches(for regex: String, in text: String) -> [String] {

do {
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex)
    let results = regex.matches(in: text,
                                range: NSRange(text.startIndex..., in: text))
    return results.map {
        String(text[Range($0.range, in: text)!])
    }
} catch let error {
    print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    return []
}
```

}

Then use it

```
let matched = matches(for: regex, in: yourstring)
print(matched)
```

SourceSafe https://stackoverflow.com/a/27880748/1187415

Comment: Yes but how to evaluate and extract this section with Swift?

Comment: The "matches" method looks very familiar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27880748/1187415 – Don't forget to add a link to the original page if you quote resources (https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)

Comment: Did you test your proposed solution?  That regex gives  an *empty array* when applied to the string from the question.

Comment: @MartinR thanks so much for the comment, it's correct and now I added the info that was missing

Comment: @LeoDabus I used your regex, but just because it wasn't the most important in the question, it's a pretty easy one, but I will add where it comes from if you felt bad...