# how go get a specific portion of a string from a point to another using char

Tags: swift, string

I need to get the part of the string with the web url from which load a web image, I need to do it from multiple images, put them in an array then use on a collection view. I used:

```
let singleArrayWithHTML = valueToCheck
let fileArray = singleArrayWithHTML.components(separatedBy: "href=")
```

in order to get the string below, but I cannot trim it further, and I cannot use a fixed index as and point, since the url could change in future

```
"http://example.com/uploads/2018/06/5.jpg" data-  lightbox="lightbox-357e45b7" class="vce-image-masonry-gallery-item"><img class="vce-image-masonry-gallery-img" src="http://example.com/wp-  content/uploads/2018/06/5.jpg" alt=""></a></div><div class="vce-image-masonry-gallery-column"><a
```

Comment: What about using NSAttributedString to convert the HTML code, and then iterate through the `NSLinkAttributeName` to get the link? Or maybe use `NSDataDetector`?

Comment: Wich link do you want? `http://example.com/uploads/2018/06/5.jpg` or `http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/5.jpg`?

Comment: the first one should be the one related directly to the image

Comment: there was an answer here, but the code disappeared!

Comment: If was the code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/50341738/1187415

Comment: thanks! do you know why the code was changed? / deteleted?

Comment: Because the author of the answer copy/pasted exactly an answer that wasn't his/her from one of his/her question. @Martin R who was the one to answer flagged it as plagiarism.