# Extracting value with backlash from string value swift

Tags: swift, regex

Hi am trying to get values of a string which is imputed in the form `"40|LQ,FP,MD,GR \"Dinner out\""`. The string value I am trying to extract is `Dinner out` the text could be different though like `ride in` but it still follows the same pattern. how can I extract this string value from the rest of the character using regex of any alternative.

Comment: Is the start of the string always the same? Should the quotes be included in the extracted string?`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try

```
var text =  "40|LQ,FP,MD,GR \"Dinner out\""

var regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\\".+?\\\"", options: [])

var matches = regex?.matches(in: text, options: []
    , range: NSMakeRange(0, text.count)) ?? []

for match in matches {
    let r = (text as NSString).substring(with: match.range)
    print("found= \(r)")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you to have a look at this question and its answers.

[Swift Get string between 2 strings in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31725424/swift-get-string-between-2-strings-in-a-string)

Quoting answer here just for your ease.

```
extension String {

func slice(from: String, to: String) -> String? {
        return (range(of: from)?.upperBound).flatMap { substringFrom in
            (range(of: to, range: substringFrom..<endIndex)?.lowerBound).map { substringTo in
                String(self[substringFrom..<substringTo])
            }
        }
    }
}
```