# multiple ranges with regex in AttributeString

Tags: swift

```
func testFunc(attribString: AttributedString)->AttributedString {

    // attribString is a markdown AttributedString for example = "Lorem ipsum dolor <test>first tag</test>sit Donec <test>second tag</test>"

    if let range = attribString.range(of: "<test>(.*?)</test>", options: .regularExpression) {

        attribString[range].foregroundColor = .red
        
    }
}
```

the documentation says:
range(of) - Finds and returns the range of the first occurrence of a given string within the string.

But how can I find the range of all occurrences in the string with regex so that I can assign it a color or other attribute?

Could a loop be a good idea?

```
for range in ranges {
     attribString[range].foregroundColor = .red
}
```

Thanks for help

Comment: You can use a `NSRegularExpression`. Also, you don't remove the tag `<test>` & `</test>` afterwards?

Comment: for use NSRegularExpression and than enumerateMatches i need a string ... regex.enumerateMatches(in: attribString  .... but attribString is an AttributeString ... thanks

Comment: Indeed. You could use `NSAttributedString` (since you can go `NSAttributedString` <-> `AttributedString`), and do it on that `NSMutableAttributedString` (mutable, since you modify it).

Comment: Or use a while/recursive loop: If you find a range, add the effect, then, break the AttributedString, from end of found range to end of it, and redo the `range(of:options:)` on the rest, etc.

Comment: have a look at this SO post "...To find all substrings that are between a starting string and an ending string."  :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31725424/swift-get-string-between-2-strings-in-a-string    look for `sliceMultipleTimes`

Comment: I have some test code that may provide a solution, but I'm not sure what you want.
 Do you want to "paint" the `first tag` etc... red?
 Do you want to keep the "markers", `<test>` and `</test>`, or you want them removed
 from the final attributed string and only have the `first tag` etc... red?

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine exactly. For me it is enough to keep the <test> </test> tags and color the whole block red. Range (of) is right, the only thing is to be able to do the same action on all selections in the text. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a possible solution to achieve `...to keep the <test> </test> tags and color the whole block red...` (adjust the code according to your needs).
It does not involve regex, it is based on the code (`sliceMultipleTimes`) at:
[Swift Get string between 2 strings in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31725424/swift-get-string-between-2-strings-in-a-string)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var attStr: AttributedString?
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(attStr ?? "nothing")
            .onAppear {
                let str = "Lorem ipsum dolor <test>first tag</test> sit Donec <test>second tag</test>"
                attStr = transform(str, from: "<test>", to: "</test>", with: .red)
            }
    }

    func transform(_ input: String, from: String, to: String, with color: Color) -> AttributedString {
        var attInput = AttributedString(input)
        let _ = input.components(separatedBy: from).compactMap { sub in
            (sub.range(of: to)?.lowerBound).flatMap { endRange in
                let s = String(sub[sub.startIndex ..< endRange])
                // use `s` for just the middle string
                if let theRange = attInput.range(of: (from + s + to)) {
                    attInput[theRange].foregroundColor = color
                }
            }
        }
        return attInput
    }
}
```