# How to extract a company name from this expression?

Tags: regex, text, between

I am struggling with what is most probably a very simple regular expression.

Consider this the text I wish to evaluate:

```
??Company=My Company Name Ltd??Address= 29 Acacia Road, Nuttytown, AA1 9AA??Description=A very rambling description here... goes on for a bit and then somemore??E-mail=bert@bertswork.com??Version=Super Plus??Expiration date=01/01/2026??First name=Bert??Last name=Bloggs??
```

I want to extract the string for **My Company Name Ltd** that is between the *Company=* and the *??Address=* tags.

Please can some kind soul put me out of my misery!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109882/regex-match-all-characters-between-two-strings

Comment: `\?{2}Company=([a-zA-Z ]+)\`

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
/(?<=\?{2}Company=)(.*?)(?=\?{2})/
```

I used lookbehind `(?<=)` and look ahead `(?=)` so that `??Company=` and `??` is not included in the match.

[<kbd>**Regex**</kbd>](https://regex101.com/r/uF4oY4/36)

Comment: Can you deepen your answer? This is not a proper answer.

Comment: [Check This](https://regex101.com/r/uF4oY4/36) @AltayMazlum

Comment: Any Issues with my regex @AltayMazlum

Comment: I never had any issue with your regex. It just would have been better if you described the details about it instead of saying _You can try this_.

Comment: I have updated my answer @AltayMazlum

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're welcome @mc1903

Answer (score 0):

Although we usually want to see what you've tried, I've been in your situation - A complete noob and not knowing even where to start, so hope this helps...

Since you know each tag starts with a `?`, you can use the following:

```
\?\?Company\=([^?]*)
```

This basically says:

1. It starts with `??Company=`
2. Take all the characters after that until you find the next `?` character and place them in a capture group.

Hope that does the trick

Comment: Thank you. I am glad you didn't ask what I had tried first before helping me. For the record: I tried google and realised I was not 'getting it'. I then had a cup of tea and a cake to make myself feel better. I then asked the community of experts and you came to my rescue. Cheers :-)