# Match a block of text between a two key words, but not if a key word is in between

Tags: regex, notepad++

Imagine I have a text file full of *cat* poems and need to find all poems that end with the word *dog*. The poems all start with the word *cat*. How do I match only poems that start with *cat* and end with *dog*?

```
Cat poem: 
My feline is very furry
I like furry felines
This is why I do not have a dog

Cat poem:
Littly furry paws
this is what i like
I don't care if it's a feline or a canine

Cat poem:
The little felines
playing in the field
sitting on the side watching is a dog
```

In my example, I want the first and last poem to be matched while the middle should not be matched. If all poems ended with *dog*, `(?=cat).*?(?<=dog)` would be an easy solution (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23756210/3270833)). However, this first matches the first poem and then the second and third poem together (as there is no *dog* in the second poem). Any extension to that regex I tried yielded just the same result, e.g. `(?=cat).*?(?!cat).*?(?<=dog)`.

I am using Notepad++ (v6.5.2) so any answer should include a solution for that. If another environment allows a more elegant solution, feel free to add that, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [**tempered greedy token**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) regex that will match substrings from `Cat` till `dog` that contain no `Cat` inside:

```
^Cat\b(?:(?!^Cat\b).)*\bdog\b(?=\R+Cat\b|\z)
```

*`.` matches newline* option must be checked. See the [*`regex demo here`*](https://regex101.com/r/qU0vS5/2).

Pattern breakdown:

- `^` - start of a line
- `Cat\b` - whole word `Cat`
- `(?:(?!^Cat\b).)*` - the tempered greedy token matching any text that is not a  whole word `Cat` at the start of a line
- `\bdog\b` - a whole word `dog`...
- `(?=\R+Cat\b|\z)` - that is either followed with 1+ newline sequence(s) (with `\R+`) and then a whole word `Cat`, or at the end of the *file* (`\z` or `\Z` are the whole string end anchors, just `\Z` allows a newline to be right after it).

[image]

Comment: Well I don't know how anyone would be able to improve on that answer inlcuding splitting up the regex, a reference link and a demo, so I'll accept this one right away! :) Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can also help me with a follow-up question: I would like to copy those two poems out of the file (or erase the middle poem, whatever is easier). I tried via `bookmark line` but that only bookmarks the first line. Any ideas?

Comment: I just found out that my answer is not precise, you need [`^Cat\b(?:(?!^Cat\b).)*\bdog\b(?=\R+Cat\b|\z)`](https://regex101.com/r/qU0vS5/2) if `dog` can be at the end of a poem line inside the poem.

Comment: You can use the following regex to remove poems like the 2nd one: `^Cat\b(?:(?!^Cat\b).)*\b(?!dog\b)\w+\b(?=\R+Cat\b|\z)`.