# split csv column into multiple columns

Tags: csv, powershell, outlook

I need some help splitting a column into multiple columns in the CSV file using powershell.

These are outlook task completion emails, and we are gathering task statistics. I need to extract the date completed and actual work data from the body column.

Here is one entry for the csv file

```
Subject,Body,From: (Name)
Task Completed: lprab: 160323-092321 - PCMS:Review/SGCE:Révision,"

Jon York


-----Original Task-----
Subject: lprab: 160323-092321 - PCMS:Review/SGCE:Révision
Priority: Normal

Start date: Wed 2016-03-23
Due date: Wed 2016-03-23

Status: Completed
% Complete: 100%
Date completed: Wed 2016-03-23
Actual work: 15 minutes

Requested by: Internet Content-PAB / Contenu d'Internet-DGAP

------------

","York, Jonathan"
```

So far, I've managed to split the body at the date completed part using this code here

```
ForEach-Object {

    $_.Body,$tempDateCompleted=$_.Body -split "Date completed: ",2
    $_ | Select-Object *,@{Name="DateCompleted";Expression={$tempDateCompleted}}

} #| export-csv
```

But I can't then get the actual date afterwards because doing

```
ForEach-Object {

    $_.Body,$tempDateCompleted=$_.Body -split "Date completed: ",2
    $_ | Select-Object *,@{Name="DateCompleted";Expression={$tempDateCompleted}}

    $_.DateCompleted,$tempActualWork=$_.Body -split "Actual work: ",2
    $_ | Select-Object *,@{Name="ActualWork";Expression={$tempActualWork}}


} #| export-csv
```

give me this error

```
Property 'DateCompleted' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.
At line:82 char:8
+     $_. <<<< DateCompleted,$tempActualWork=$_.Body -split "Actual work: ",2
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
```

My ultimate goal would be to have the following output

Subject, From, DateCompleted, ActualWork
"Task name","Jon York","2016-03-23","15 minutes"

Thanks!

Comment: So every entry starts and stops with `Subject,Body,From: (Name)`. This is not a CSV at all from the looks of what you posted. Ahh Ok Is the body a multi-lined  field then which is why it looks like it does.

Comment: Would a bunch of regular expressions work better?

Comment: Sort of.... Just wait I got this. Just finishing my test and answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would love to introduce you to [`ConvertFrom-StringData`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849900(v=wps.620).aspx) that will convert that body into a hash table that we then will convert into a proper object for you to output.

```
 $source = Import-Csv C:\temp\text.csv
 $data = Foreach($row in $source){
    $newHash =  $row.Body -split "`r`n" | Where-Object{$_ -match ":"} | Foreach-object{
        $_ -replace "^(.*?):",'$1='
    } | Out-String |ConvertFrom-StringData

    $newHash.Subject = $row.Subject
    $newHash.From = $row.'From: (Name)'

    New-Object -TypeName pscustomobject -Property $newHash
 }
```

This takes the `$_.Body` on turns it into a string array split on newlines. Then we filter out any entry that does not have a ":". For each of those entries we replace the *first* colon with an equals sign (as required by `ConvertFrom-StringData`). This works well so you don't have to build a bunch of regex patterns to match each property you want thereby making it easier to add and remove properties in your output. We build on that hashtable with the other 2 entries from the original row.

Now `$data` contains the complex object containing all the details of the entry.

```
% Complete     : 100%
Date completed : Wed 2016-03-23
Start date     : Wed 2016-03-23
From           : York, Jonathan
Priority       : Normal
Status         : Completed
Subject        : Task Completed: lprab: 160323-092321 - PCMS:Review/SGCE:Révision
Actual work    : 15 minutes
Due date       : Wed 2016-03-23
Requested by   : Internet Content-PAB / Contenu d'Internet-DGAP
```

Now you just need to do stuff with it like your export. Since some of the fields have spaces we need to quote those properties.

```
$data | select Subject,"Date completed","Actual work",From | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation $path
```

Comment: So if I then wanted to output a CSV with just Subject, Date completed, Actual Work and From, what would that bit of code look like?

Comment: @JonYork Added a little more on the bottom to help with that.

Answer (score 0):

_If you want to pull out the date completed you can use a RegEx pattern, something like this:

`$_.body -match 'Date completed:.*\n' | Out-Null;$matches[0] -replace "Date completed: ",""`

Keep in mind that when you use `-match` the results are stored in a variable `$matches`. In this example, you'd get (for that line): `Wed 2016-03-23`

Then you can assign that wherever you want. It only selects the line with `Date completed:` up until the line break, and then you use string formatting tools to remove the Date completed bit. You could use similar logic for your other lines and assign them as needed.

**Edit:**
You can also use a [lookbehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109882/regex-match-all-characters-between-two-strings) to avoid using the string formatting, it just hurts my head because I don't use it too often:

`$_.body -match '(?<=Date completed: ).*\n' | Out-Null;$matches[0]`

**Edit 2:**

Since you already are using a foreach, you could do something like this:

```
#Create a collection you can easily add to
$Results = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

#...read the file

ForEach-Object {

    $obj = @{
        Subject = $e.Subject
        From = $_.'From: (Name)'
    }

    if ($_.Body -match '(?<=Actual work: ).*\n') {$obj["Actual Work"] = $matches[0]} 
      else {$obj["Actual Work"] = $null}

    if ($_.Body -match '(?<=Date Completed: ).*\n') {$obj["Date Completed"] = $matches[0]}
      else {$obj["Date Completed"] = $null}

    $Results.Add($Obj) | Out-Null

}

$Results | Export-CSV
```

Your result objects would look something like this:

```
Name              Value                                                                                        
----              -----                                                                                        
Subject           Task Completed: l...                             
From              York, Jonathan                                                                               
Date Completed    Wed 2016-03-23...                                                                            
Actual Work       15 minutes...
```

If you were to go about it this way, use an `ArrayList` so that you can add to the collection without having to completely rebuild it each time (because your standard `@()` collections are a fixed size and have to be copied to a new collection of size+1 each time you do a += type add) and pipe your call to add to the collection to `Out-Null` to remove the output (the index you just added the item to).

When you do the `-match` you get a boolean true or false response. If you wrap it in the if/else statement like this, you can handle what happens if you *don't* find a result - in this case just leaving the value empty.

Matt's answer is also a great way to go about it too!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the info everyone gave me, it wasn't working nearly as well as I was hoping. It may be a bit of a long winded solution, but it works well, and predictably.

I needed to pipe the imported content as an out-string to get multiple regular expressions to work as expected, and to pipe the string back out as a csv file again, I needed to encode it as Ascii.

```
$text = (Get-Content c:\Tools\export.csv) | out-string

$regex = "(?sm),""\s.*?Date completed: "
$replace = ',"'
$output = [regex]::replace($text,$regex,$replace)

$regex = "[\r\n]+Actual work: "
$replace = '","'
$output = [regex]::replace($output,$regex,$replace)

$regex = "(?sm)Requested by:\s.*?"","""
$replace = ',"'
$output = [regex]::replace($output,$regex,$replace)

$regex = '"Mon '
$replace = '"'
$output = [regex]::replace($output,$regex,$replace)

$regex = '"Tue '
$replace = '"'
$output = [regex]::replace($output,$regex,$replace)

$regex = '"Wed '
$replace = '"'
$output = [regex]::replace($output,$regex,$replace)

$regex = '"Thu '
$replace = '"'
$output = [regex]::replace($output,$regex,$replace)

$regex = '"Fri '
$replace = '"'
$output = [regex]::replace($output,$regex,$replace)

$regex = "(?sm) minute(.)\s.*?,"""
$replace = '","minute","'
$output = [regex]::replace($output,$regex,$replace)

$regex = "(?sm) hour(.)\s.*?,"""
$replace = '","hour","'
$output = [regex]::replace($output,$regex,$replace)

$regex = "(?sm) day(.)\s.*?,"""
$replace = '","day","'
$output = [regex]::replace($output,$regex,$replace)

$regex = "(?sm) week(.)\s.*?,"""
$replace = '","week","'
$output = [regex]::replace($output,$regex,$replace)

$regex = "(?sm),""\/O=CO\S.*?"",,""Normal"""
$replace = ''
$output = [regex]::replace($output,$regex,$replace)

$regex = "(?sm)""Task Declined\S.*?""Task"
$replace = '"Task'
$output = [regex]::replace($output,$regex,$replace)

$regex = "(?sm)""Subject\S.*?Sensitivity"""
$replace = '"Subject","Date Completed","Time","Factor","Developper"'
$output = [regex]::replace($output,$regex,$replace)

$output | Out-file c:\Tools\output.csv -Encoding ascii
```

Now the sample entry in the csv file looks like this

```
"Subject","Date Completed","Time","Factor","Developper"
"Task Completed: lprab: 160323-092321 - PCMS:Review/SGCE:R?vision","2016-03-23","15","minute","York, Jonathan"
```