# Remove from <!--[if gte mso 9]> to <![endif]--> in HTML [REGEX, RUBY]

Tags: html, ruby, regex, if-statement, replace

I have a HTML text with <!--[if gte mso 9]> and <![endif]--> tags. I want to remove everything that there is between those two tags.
I'm using the ruby function gsub with a Regex expression, but it won't work.

This is what I've tried:

```
text = "<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>\n <w:WordDocument>\n [...] \n</style>\n<![endif]-->"

text2 = text.gsub /(?=<!\-\-\[if gte mso 9\]>)(.*?)(?<=<!\[endif\]\-\->)/, ""
```

What I want as an answer is:

```
text2 = "<!--[if gte mso 9]><![endif]-->"
```

Or even:

```
text2 = ""
```

I tried this based on [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109882/regex-match-all-characters-between-two-strings)

I've tried [this](https://regex101.com/) online Regex tester and, it seems to be the right way to do it, but it won't work on my program!

Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this regex `/(?<=<!--\[if gte mso 9\]>).*?(?=<!\[endif\]-->)/m`, and do a `gsub` on the string. You will get `<!--[if gte mso 9]><![endif]-->`

- `(?<=<!--\[if gte mso 9\]>)` is a positive look behind, which matches the `<!--\[if gte mso 9\]>` string, but doesn't include it in the result.
- `.*` matches any characters 0 or more times.
- `(?=<!\[endif\]-->)` is a positive look forward, which matches the `<!\[endif\]-->` but doesn't include it in the result.
- the `m` identifier at the end means the match multiline strings. Since you declared your string with "", the `\n` will be interpreted as a new line.

Essentially, you are matching everything in between the two tags.

In your regex, `/(?=<!\-\-\[if gte mso 9\]>)(.*?)(?<=<!\[endif\]\-\->)/`, you used the positive look forward for the first tag, and positive look behind for the second tag, you need to flip them.

- Positive look forward matches a group after the main expression without including it in the result.
- Positive look behind matches a group before the main expression without including it in the result.

Comment: I think you meant `.*`, not `.0`.  But you should use `.*?`, like the OP did.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much! It solved in a minute!

Comment: Great answer! How can this be modified to include <!--[if gte mso 9]><![endif]--> as part of the capture?