# How to write this REGEX - php?

Tags: php, regex

I have this string: `list_tablename.json.php?type=arr`.
I need to grab the `tablemane`.
I could achieve this task through a combination of `stripos()` and `substr()`.
I would like to know how to accomplish this using regex. 
In fact how to grab everything between `_` and first `.` ?

Following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109882/regex-match-all-characters-between-two-strings), this pattern `(?<=_)(.+)(.json)` should work, but it is not. 
[regex](https://regex101.com/r/dH4V7C/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a positive lookbehind for `_`, and get the portion till next `.`:

```
(?<=_)[^.]+
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/k7W5Vg/1)