# How to select a portion of a string in R?

Tags: r, regex, string, subset

I have strings like below one in a big text file. How can i select only the part in second line between `"SN="` and `":2832397"` i.e. `"RK:7573-0"` out of it?

```
SIGN="000F 0E70 FA83 B72F D215 C7EE 4AF4 6440 A547 12B1 0603 \

SN=RK:7573-0:2832397:369963

1086 0857 BFF1 5FC2 CE6F C87D 7C00 DF64 C1AD DD39") }
```

Comment: using regular expression with `gsub` would be your best bet, maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109882/regex-match-all-characters-between-two-strings can be of assistance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
as.vector(na.omit(str_extract(lines, "(?<=SN=).*(?=:2832397)")))
#[1] "RK:7573-0"
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
gsub("^[^=]+\\=|(:\\d+){2,}$", "", grep("SN=", lines, value = TRUE))
#[1] "RK:7573-0"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start with a regex like this :

> SN=([A-Z]+:[\d-]+):

exemple : https://regex101.com/r/0qBwYc/1

explanation :

`SN=`  => match literaly "SN="

`[A-Z]+`  => match 1 or any upercase

`:`  => match literaly ":"

`[\d-]+` => match any digit or the caracter "-" 1 time or more

`:`  => match literaly ":"

`([A-Z]+:[\d-]+)` => parenthesis are use to create a matching group so you can get only the part who match "[A-Z]+:[\d-]+"