# how to match a specific enclosed pattern and anything in between with REGEX in JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match a pattern like this %data% in a string.

Although it can be easy but i need solution that can be robust for a big and multiline string.

**For e.g.**: i would like to match only the first and second matching %% combination and third and fourth (etc. etc.) in the following:

> this %data% is not %data that i want to % show up in the results. %
>   some more demo text %

I would like to match only the parts

> %data%

,

> %data that i want to %

,

> % some more demo text %

from the above string..

**I have tried:**

I was trying to use this pattern but its selecting all of it from the first % to the last % symbol..

```
/^\%[\s\S]*\%$/gm
```

If this question has been asked and you want to close it.. just point me in the right direction and close it if you want.. thanks.

**it is not the same question as marked by many..** with the title:

> Regex Match all characters between two strings

and url: [url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109882/regex-match-all-characters-between-two-strings)
as it is normal regular expression and not the one in JS (as JS doesn't support lookbehind) and it doesn't have the pair matching problem as mine.. hence, its completely different i think..

---

**I would really like a good description of the RegEX** if someone can provide it with the answer.. as i am not well versed in reading much complicated RegEx's, just getting used to it.. and **i would also like an explanation of why my code is breaking and doesn't work** to help me in future..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex Match all characters between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109882/regex-match-all-characters-between-two-strings)

Comment: for this propouse you can use charAt for read each caracter and make conuter 0  start  1 end, to get text insde and position in string. IDe Twig https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/tree/2.x/lib/Twig

Comment: Try [regular expressions 101](https://regex101.com/r/CD1Oda/2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
/%(.*?)%/g
```

this lazily captures (i.e, as few times as possible, expanding as needed) everything between two `%`.

an alternative of this :

```
/%([^%]*)%/g
```

in this one, we're not matching lazily, instead we match (and capture) everything but a `%` after `%`

**Working output using this regex :**

```js
const regex = /%(.*?)%/g;
const str = `this %data% is not %data that i want to % show up in the results. % some more demo text %`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: `/%([^%]*)%/g` is more efficient

Comment: It will, because if you exclude it from the match then you won't *skip* the characters between the 2nd and 3rd `%`.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I understand and get that both are working and are good.. but can you tell me that, if i want to add the new line character in the match as well (as the "." dot character does not matches that), in this regex /%(.*?)%/g  , how can i do that. and why doesn't adding \n inside the regular brackets like so /%([\n.]*?)%/gm doesn't work ?

Comment: @Vimal__Frontendweb you can use : `[\s\S]` instead of `.` dot, to match even the new line character, `[\n.]` doesn't work because `.` doesn't have any special meaning when it's inside `[]`. see live demo here : https://regex101.com/r/dRPi5c/1

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need:

Regex:

```
(?<=\%)(.*?)(?=\%)
```

Input:

> sdgsg%data%dgsgdsg

Output:

> data