# Java: how to extract information "rel="self"" with regex

Tags: java, regex

I would like to extract all urls and "rel" informations associated in this string:

```
<https://api-staging.xxx.com/v1/users>; rel="self", <https://api-staging.xxx.com/v1/users?page=1,0>; rel="next"
```

So I've started with:

```
Pattern mentionPattern = Pattern.compile("<(.+?)>");
Matcher mentionMatcher = mentionPattern.matcher(url);
```

It works perfectly for URL, but I don't know how to extract "rel" informations. In this example I want to extract "self" and "next".

Thank you very much guys

Comment: Not your down-voter, but if you're parsing HTML, why not use a dedicated HTML parser? Or if XML, same: why not use a dedicated XML parser?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex Match all characters between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109882/regex-match-all-characters-between-two-strings)

Comment: Did you look at [the methods of Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way:

```
String test = "<https://api-staging.xxx.com/v1/users>; rel=\"self\", <https://api-staging.xxx.com/v1/users?page=1,0>; rel=\"next\"";
Pattern mentionPattern = Pattern.compile("[<\"](?<content>.+?)[>\"]");
Matcher m = mentionPattern.matcher(test);
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group("content")); // using named groups
}
```

This prints:

```
https://api-staging.xxx.com/v1/users
self
https://api-staging.xxx.com/v1/users?page=1,0
next
```