# Extracting the RGB value from a string

Tags: ios, swift, rgb

How would I extract the RBG value from the following string?:

`let string = "<span style=\"background-color: rgb(230, 0, 0);\">`

I would like to get extract `"rgb(230, 0, 0)"` from the `background-color` value, so I can convert it to a hex string and update some UI.

```
let range = string.range(of: "\"background-color: ")
let startPoint = range.location + range.length
let subString = string.substring(from: startPoint)
//generating error claiming 'cannot convert value of type 'int' to expected argument type 'string.index'. 
//paused here to ask S.O b/c I do not think substrings is the best way to do this, maybe there is a library that extracts values from html elements, or regex?
```

Comment: https://github.com/100mango/SwiftCssParser seems useful

Comment: -1, and voting to close... Seriously, as a «lead iOS developer» (based on your profile), you should at least try something and ask specific questions... «Plz give me the code» is not acceptable here.

Comment: Moreover, why would you want a hex value, when the built in initializer for `UIColor` accepts RGBA values, not hex.

Comment: Wow guys!! the flame is on super high today!  Thanks to Leo for supplying the answer for me.  I was struggling for ~20 minutes to get my foot off the ground, hence the lack of code until my answer. 

 I dont think S.O is a place to talk smack on each other.  We are all in this to help each other out!

Comment: You're right... But then at least please show some effort...

Comment: I'm downvoting, because in my opinion there is a lack of tries. Not because your profile says you are a iOS Lead Developer, I clearly don't care about that, but because you have enough reputation to know what a good question should looks like. Some tries with a regex (maybe showing one not working), some tries with `rangeOf`, etc. An explanation on your context, is the string always looking like this, do you have other variants (not a `background-color`, but other possible attributes), etc.

Comment: Alrighty then, Ill update my question with my originial try, which was incredibly wrong

Comment: Even if I still find it of poor quality (error is explicit, but that's my experience talking and since I do not take in account your coding skills), I consider it not that bad enough to keep my downvote, so I remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23756210/2303865) to get the string between two strings:

```
let string = "<span style=\"background-color: rgb(230, 0, 0);\">"

let pattern = "(?<=background-color: )(.*)(?=;)"
if let rgb = string.range(of: pattern, options: .regularExpression).map({String(string[$0])}) {
    print(rgb)  // "rgb(230, 0, 0)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let range = (string as NSString).range(of: "\"background-color: ")
let startPoint = range.location + range.length
let subString = (string as NSString).substring(from: startPoint)
let deliminator = ";"
let components = subString.components(separatedBy: deliminator)
let rgb = components[0]

print(rgb) -> "rgb(230, 0, 0)"
```

Comment: Your answer won't work with the string in your question. The string in your question does not contain the string `"color: rgb(`. And why are you using `NSString` in Swift?

Comment: And your question states you want to extract `rgb(230, 0, 0)` but this answer only extracts `230, 0, 0`.

Comment: Im using NSString b/c NSString substring(from: ) method accepts an int but the String subString(from: ) accepts a string.index.  

And yes, I updated my answer to extract rgb(230, 0, 0) instead of the digits, sorry.

Comment: If you use just `String` methods, you will get ranges that work with `String`. There is no need to use `NSString`.

Comment: well, this is not the correct to handle this, as regex is much more graceful, but got your point