# Find multiple instances of substring in a string using Regular Expressions?

Tags: c++, regex, string

I have many lines such as this:

```
string s = "Some HTML with two <A HREF="links"> in one <A HREF="line">";
```

I need to use regular expressions to get the URLs in between the quotation marks, like this:

```
string all_links[] = {"links", "line"};
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Maybe take a look at [std::sregex_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator).

Comment: If you could give us what you tried, we can help you to find where goes wrong.

Comment: You need an HTML parser to do this reliably. You do not want to do this with regular expressions. HTML seems stupid simple at first, but there's a lot of nuances and ambiguity that can prove increasingly frustrating, especially when you expose this code to real-world data where not everyone follows the rules.

Comment: This answer possibly helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109882/regex-match-all-characters-between-two-strings

Answer (score 0):

As per your given string sample.
Use `[^\HREF="]+(?=">)`

[Demo](https://regexr.com/3hqpm)