# REGEX Match line containing string between two other lines

Tags: regex, findstr

I am trying to match every line containing the string "Random Data" only if its between "Index 100" including that string. Is this possible?

> Index 000
>
> **Index 100**
>
> Random Data Random Data
>
> Not Random Data
>
> Random Data Random Data
>
> Not Random Data
>
> **Index 100**
>
> Random Data Random Data
>
> Not Random Data
>
> Random Data Random Data
>
> Not Random Data
>
> **Index 100**
>
> Index 200

Can't seem to get it, I was playing around on https://regexr.com/ but no luck.

I took the regex from this post [Regex Match all characters between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109882/regex-match-all-characters-between-two-strings)

and attempted to modify it with no luck. I tried this

```
(?<=Index 100)\R*Random*\R*(?=Index 200)
```

I am completley new to regex, a little direction would be great.

Comment: Are you using it in `findstr`?

Comment: What is this? A webpage? A text file?

Comment: This requires programmatic logic to do, at least if you are trying to find all instances of "Random Data" but not "Not Random Data"; otherwise you'll only match the first or last between two Index 100 values. `findstr` is also appears to have very limited regex abilities and probably can't do this; you'd be much better off using `select-string` if you have access to PowerShell. Finally, you would need `\r?\n` to match line breaks instead of `\R` unless findstr has some special meaning for `\R`

Comment: The question is very unclear: tagged with `findstr`, tests performed in a JavaScript regex tester, and the pattern is actually PCRE/Java/Boost/Onigmo compatible. Too unclear.

Comment: Yes the plan is to use findstr, this is for a text file. I am new to regex so I wasn't sure if this was possible with regular expressions. Thank you all.