# How do I search for a range of Strings

Tags: swift, string, search, range, swift4

How do I search for a range of Strings,
I want to search userID

But userID may this time is "123", 
next time is "zxvcvb", 
so i can't use offsetBy

```
let userID = "12345"
let URL = "http://test/main/?Username=\(userID)#!/index.php"
let firstIndex = URL.index(of: "=")
let secondIndex = URL.index(of: "#")
let range = firstIndex...secondIndex //error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
let userID = "jshjdschd"
let url = "http://test/main/?Username=\(userID)#!/index.php"

    guard let firstIndex = url.index(of: "="),
        let secondIndex = url[firstIndex...].index(of: "#") else{
            print("UserId not found")
    }

let range = url.index(after: firstIndex)..<secondIndex
let mySubstring = url[range]
print(mySubstring) //jshjdschd
```

Comment: Note that `URL` is a native type. It is Swift naming convention to name the variables starting with a lowercase letter. Btw this would crash the app if the characters are found in the wrong order. You can avoid the crash searching the substring `url[firstIndex...].index(of: "#")`

Comment: @LeoDabus : My mistake, I just take code from question. Updated. Thanks

Comment: Btw instead of dropping the first letter just use the index after the firstIndex. `let range = url.index(after: firstIndex)..<secondIndex`

Comment: @LeoDabus: I was searching for this solution. Thanks

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: you are real nerd. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109882/regex-match-all-characters-between-two-strings/23756210#23756210) to get the range of the user ID between those two strings:

```
let userID = "12345"
let pattern = "(?<=Username=)(.*)(?=#!)"
let link = "http://test/main/?Username=\(userID)#!/index.php"
if let range = link.range(of: pattern, options: .regularExpression) {
     let id = link[range]
     print("id:", id)    // "id: 12345\n"
}
```