# Get all strings between two curly braces using regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to get an array of all strings that are contained in curly brackets using JavaScript.

```
 {{text is here}}
```

note that the text could contain all special characters and could be multi line  i have tried this so far
 [regex test](https://regex101.com/r/gYXSbO/3/)

```
\{{(.*?)\}}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex Match all characters between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109882/regex-match-all-characters-between-two-strings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your demo you enabled `m` flag which is a wrong flag here. You need `s` flag or even without flags:

```
{{([^]*?)}}
```

Note: You don't need to escape braces here.

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/gYXSbO/10)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
(?<=\{{)(.*?)(?=\}})
```

it works for

```
{{text is here}}
```

https://regex101.com/r/gYXSbO/7/

Comment: But it also work for {text is here} which is not what is asked.

Comment: @Nirnae - updated my answer to `(?<=\{{)(.*?)(?=\}})`

Comment: Lookbehinds are not supported by all major browsers yet.