# Regex find within two strings

Tags: regex, eclipse

I have searched for this, but the results have not worked out for me.

I am trying to use Regex to find/replace in Eclipse and I think I'm close.

For example, I want to search this text and find 'Award'.

```
<columns>
    <field>Opportunity.Site_Country__c</field>
</columns>
<currency>USD</currency>
<filter>
    <criteriaItems>
        <column>STAGE_NAME</column>
        <operator>equals</operator>
        <value>Award,Award.,Order</value>
    </criteriaItems>
    <language>en_US</language>
</filter>
<format>Tabular</format>
<name>opportunity site update</name>
```

My attempt is this which somewhat works:

```
(?<=\<column>STAGE_NAME<\/column>[\s\S]*)(Award\b)(?=[\s\S]*<\/value>[\s\S]*<\/criteriaItems>)
```

Comment: Your answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Ha, I beat you to it @SpencerWieczorek

Comment: @AnthonyRussell Yeah, had a problem finding it for a few seconds :P

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex Match all characters between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109882/regex-match-all-characters-between-two-strings)