# Python: Regex parsing between two quotes

Tags: python, regex

If I have this text blob

```
"merchants":[{"name":"Berlins - Venice","description":"LA\'s Most 
 Authentic German Döner Experience.","should_show_ajax_etas":true,"id":3916
,"fulfillment_types_allowed":["DELIVERY"],,"name":"Clutch CaliMex",
"description":"Northern Mexican Cuisine."name":"LocaliVenice",
"description":"If 7-Eleven and Whole Foods Had A Love 
Child...","should_show_ajax_etas":true,"id":1743
```

I am trying to parse the `name` value between the quotes. So in case, I am trying to return `Berlins - Venice`, `Clutch CaliMex`, and `LocaliVenice`. This is the regex that I am using on [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

```
regex = re.compile(r'?<=\"name\":\")(.*)(?=\"description\"').
```

which is mostly inspired by [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109882/regex-match-all-characters-between-two-strings)

However, it appears to return EVERYTHING from `Berlins` to the very last instance of `description` even though there are two more instances of `description` in the text blob.

```
Berlins - Venice","description"..(truncated).."name":"Locali Venice",
```

Again, I only need the name of the restaurants in between the quotes

Comment: This is JSON, better to use the builtin json packages to parse, than do it yourself with regex.

Comment: This is a text blob after parsing it using BeautifulSoup. Recreating it would take even more time

Comment: Use `json.loads()` to deserialize, then just select the fields you want.

Comment: Try this: (?<=\"name\":\")(.*)(?=\",)