# How to find SELECT * statement with regex

Tags: php, regex, refactoring

I'm searching for all SELECT * like queries in my code base to replace it with the actual name of the columns.

I'm trying to build a regex that can find if a '*' is found between the word SELECT and FROM.

This should match the following patterns :

```
   #1 SELECT * FROM tablename
   #2 SELECT tablename.* FROM tablename
   #3 SELECT tb1.col1, tb2.* FROM table tb1, table2 tb2
```

But not this one :

```
 #4 SELECT col FROM table
```

My attempts so far (in the search box of PhpStorm):

```
SELECT *
```

Output: 1, 2, 3 and 4

I also tried the answer from [Regex Match all characters between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109882/regex-match-all-characters-between-two-strings)

```
(?<=SELECT)(.*)(?=FROM)
```

Output: 1, 2, 3 and 4

I went further in StackOverflow and found this one:

```
SELECT\s+?[^\s]+?\s+?FROM\s+?[^\s]+?\s+?WHERE.
```

Output: 1, 2, 3 and 4

Can you help me please ?

Comment: Search from where?

Comment: How did you try? Share your regex attempts along with current output

Comment: I will use grep to search in my entire codebase (php)

Comment: Hey why is my question down voted ? I'm quite sure this hasn't asked exactly the same way. I understand it might be not well formulated. I apologize, it's my first question here. Can you help me to formulate it better so it can be clearer and more useful to other people ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are encountering is that `*` in regex language is a meta character which means that it has a special meaning like `.+?[]{}()^$\` to retreive their literal meaning they should be preceded with a `\` or between squared brackets.
So to match a `*` the regex can be `\*`.
Following regex uses an atomic group and a lookahead assertion to ensure there is no `SELECT` or `FROM` word between `SELECT` and `*`

```
SELECT(?>(?!SELECT|FROM).)*\*
```