# Regex: Capture everything between two strings except those strings

Tags: regex

I have the following texts:

> This text appears at p.UNWANTED_TEXT72
>
> This text appears between pp.UNWANTED_TEXT12-14

I want to select text between `p.` and first digit occurred and remove it:

Here is what I want:

> This text appears at p.72.
>
> This text appears between pp.12-14.

The following expression captures boundaries as well:

```
p\.(.*?)\d
```

How can I exclude the boundaries from selection?

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/Ppxzpb/1/)

Comment: Which tool/programming language are you using?

Comment: R, but does that matter?

Comment: There are many different flavors of Regex. That is why the tool/programming language should be in the question (as explained if you hover over the regex tag). I don't know R so I'm not sure if it allows look-arounds, but you could try `(?<=p\.)(.*?)(?=\d)`. If that works it's a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109882/regex-match-all-characters-between-two-strings

Comment: It matters because the different regex engines have different feature sets. Specifically for your case one could use zero-width look-behind assertions, but that is not supported by all dialects. If these are not supported but look-ahead is, you can still do just the look-ahead for the digit and replace the matched occurences with a `p.`.

Comment: R is using ERE (default) or Perl regexes. What are you using?

Comment: Yes, it looks like it depends on the program. When I use `gsub` function in R with `perl=TRUE`, @Ivar 's solution worked, otherwise not. Working code in R: `gsub(pattern = "(?<=p\\.)(.*?)(?=\\d)", replacement = "", x = "This text appears at p.UNWANTED_TEXT72", perl = TRUE)`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a [positive lookbehind](https://regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and a [negated (shorthand) character class](https://regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html): `(?<=p\.)\D+`