# Regex Match all characters between two strings including tail

Tags: regex, regex-group

I'd like to search for all the compilation flags in an expression such as:

`-Xaa=2000 -tbb:simple   -Xcc-dds -g -c -DC_hh -Xii-ff-file -Xmm-nn -Xkk -o output/gg.o -ee1481 -Xll=0x1000 -I. -I./ss/tt/uu -I./ss/tt/ww -I./EIS_CFG/gentool/make -I./testenv`

Using rexex, so that each flag is in its own group.
I have come as far as:

`(?<= -)(.*?)(?= \-)`

which I found in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109882/regex-match-all-characters-between-two-strings?noredirect=1&lq=1) , and it finds everything except the last flag, as it requires each group to have a ' -' after it.
How can I also get hold of the last flag?

Edit after I accepted the answer:

Is it possible to include the '-' inside the group?

Also, if the pattern contains a .c / .cpp file to compile, is it possible to remove it?

For example in:

`-Xaa=2000 -tbb:simple   -Xcc-dds -g -c -DC_hh -Xii-ff-file -Xmm-nn -Xkk -o output/gg.o -ee1481 -Xll=0x1000 -I. ./ff/gg/vv.c -I./ss/tt/uu -I./ss/tt/ww -I./EIS_CFG/gentool/make -I./testenv`

Get all groups without the `./ff/gg/vv.c`

Comment: What about `(?<= -)(.*?)(?=$|\s+-)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
(?<= |^)(-\S+)(?= |$)
```

This pattern says to:

```
(?<= |^)    assert that what precedes is either a space OR
            what precedes is the very start of the string

(-\S+)      then match and capture everything non whitespace character until

(?= |$)     what follows is another space OR
            what follows is the end of the string
```

### Demo

Comment: I edited my question after accepting your answer. Couid you please extend your answer to include the rest of the question? Thanks :)

Comment: @Carma I updated my answer per your new requirements.  Check the demo to see that the regex pattern does not capture the source or output file path.

Comment: Thanks! The parameter after -o belongs to  the -o even though it's separated by a space. Only a parameter which ends in .c / .cpp should be removed. This is not some random requirement - it's how compilation flags are interpreted by the compiler...

Comment: I am not updating again.  This is the _second_ time you have changed your question.  You should ask a new question at this point.  Generally speaking, you really need a parser, not a regex, to handle this.