# Extract integers after double space with regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas, extract

I have a dataframe where I want to extract stuff after double space. For all rows in column `NAME` there is a double white space after the company names before the integers.

```
                                    NAME  INVESTMENT  PERCENT
0     APPLE COMPANY A  57 638 232 stocks     OIL LTD  0.12322
1  BANANA 1 COMPANY B  12 946 201 stocks    GOLD LTD  0.02768
2     ORANGE COMPANY C  8 354 229 stocks     GAS LTD  0.01786

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'NAME': ['APPLE COMPANY A  57 638 232 stocks', 'BANANA 1 COMPANY B  12 946 201 stocks', 'ORANGE COMPANY C  8 354 229 stocks'],
    'PERCENT': [0.12322, 0.02768 , 0.01786]
    })
```

I have this earlier, but it also includes integers in the company name:

```
df['STOCKS']=df['NAME'].str.findall(r'\b\d+\b').apply(lambda x: ''.join(x))
```

Instead I tried to extract after double spaces

```
df['NAME'].str.split('(\s{2})')
```

which gives output:

```
0       [APPLE COMPANY A,   , 57 638 232 stocks]
1    [BANANA 1 COMPANY B,   , 12 946 201 stocks]
2       [ORANGE COMPANY C,   , 8 354 229 stocks]
```

However, I want the integers that occur after double spaces to be joined/merged and put into a new column.

```
                 NAME  PERCENT  STOCKS
0     APPLE COMPANY A  0.12322  57638232
1  BANANA 1 COMPANY B  0.02768  12946201
2    ORANGE COMPANY C  0.01786  12946201
```

How can I modify my second function to do what I want?

Comment: Why do you want to use regex ? it's slow and you can just split on 2 spaces (`.split('  ')`) also, i assume that by removing your first column and creating a new one while putting the content into it it'd work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the original logic you may use

```
df['STOCKS'] = df['NAME'].str.extract(r'\s{2,}(\d+(?:\s\d+)*)', expand=False).str.replace(r'\s+', '')
df['NAME'] = df['NAME'].str.replace(r'\s{2,}\d+(?:\s\d+)*\s+stocks', '')
```

Output:

```
                 NAME  PERCENT    STOCKS
0     APPLE COMPANY A  0.12322  57638232
1  BANANA 1 COMPANY B  0.02768  12946201
2    ORANGE COMPANY C  0.01786   8354229
```

**Details**

- `\s{2,}(\d+(?:\s\d+)*)` is used to extract the first occurrence of whitespace-separated consecutive digit chunks after 2 or more whitespaces and `.replace(r'\s+', '')` removes any whitespaces in that extracted text afterwards
- `.replace(r'\s{2,}\d+(?:\s\d+)*\s+stocks'` updates the text in the `NAME` column, it removes 2 or more whitespaces, consecutive whitespace-separated digit chunks and then 1+ whitespaces and `stocks`. Actually, the last `\s+stocks` may be replaced with `.*` if there are other words.

Comment: regex should not be the best solution, but this works fine so, up for this

Comment: I get the error message: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str' for `df['NAME'].str.extract(r'\s{2,}(\d+(?:\s\d+)*)').str.replace('\s+', '')`

Comment: @Mataunited17 I used the data from your question and it works in my Python 3.6.

Comment: I see. I am using 3.7.1. Strange.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to make it compatible with my version?

Comment: @Mataunited17 Added `expand=False` so that `extract` only returned the series and tested in Python 3.7. Also works in Python 3.6.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes. It worked. Thanks. I think I will accept your answer, it explained more than the other answer.

Answer (score 3):

Another `pandas` approach, which will cast `STOCKS` to numeric type:

```
df_split = (df['NAME'].str.extractall('^(?P<NAME>.+)\s{2}(?P<STOCKS>[\d\s]+)')
            .reset_index(level=1, drop=True))

df_split['STOCKS'] = pd.to_numeric(df_split.STOCKS.str.replace('\D', ''))
```

Assign these columns back into your original `DataFrame`:

```
df[['NAME', 'STOCKS']] = df_split[['NAME', 'STOCKS']]

         COMPANY_NAME    STOCKS  PERCENT
0     APPLE COMPANY A  57638232  0.12322
1  BANANA 1 COMPANY B  12946201  0.02768
2    ORANGE COMPANY C   8354229  0.01786
```

Comment: This solution was the best so far. However, does the solution replace any other column that exists from before? My original dataframe has 3 columns.

Comment: It wont replace, it creates a new `DataFrame`. I can update my answer to assign back into the original df if that's preferred?

Comment: Thanks for the edit! This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use look behind and look ahead operators.

```
''.join(re.findall(r'(?<=\s{2})(.*)(?=stocks)',string)).replace(' ','')
```

This catches all characters **between two spaces and the word stocks** and replace all the spaces with null.

Another Solution using Split

```
df["NAME"].apply(lambda x:x[x.find('  ')+2:x.find('stocks')-1].replace(' ',''))
```

Reference:-

1. [Look_behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109882/regex-match-all-characters-between-two-strings)

Comment: Or he could just do `.split('   ')[1].split()[0]` which is way faster than regex (2 spaces in the first split)

Comment: @Mataunited17 can you show me what you tried to do ? that should work just fine

Comment: @Nenri I did `df['NAME'].str.split(' ')[1].split()[0]` which gave me error: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'. Which is strange, because I have a dataframe.

Comment: yeah, and `.str` is supposed to return you a string

Comment: @Justice_Lords When I applied your second solution to my original dataframe, the outcome is strange when the names are very long. Is there a way to fix this? I think it has to do with the `+2` part of `x:x[x.find('  ')+2:x.find('stocks')`

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
df['STOCKS'] = df['NAME'].str.split(',')[2].replace(' ', '')
df['NAME'] = df['NAME'].str.split(',')[0]
```

Comment: Thx, but still, there's no comma in his string, you should split on spaces and as one has 2 spaces, it should be `.split()[3].split()[0]`

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to change it

Comment: @Vaghinak this didn't work either. I get the error message: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: @Mataunited17 'cause you need to split on spaces and yeah this answer is false, he forgot a lot of things

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without using regex by using split.

```
df['STOCKS'] = df['NAME'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x.split('  ')[1].split(' ')[:-1]))
df['NAME'] = df['NAME'].str.replace(r'\s?\d+(?:\s\d+).*', '')
```