# I am trying to write python script to find a string in file with more than 1000 lines and delete few lines (10) after that string match

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below fastfile (more than 1000 lines) I would like to search for string "Validate repo test2" and delete lines starting from "Validate repo test2" upto string "end" 
and rewrite content to new file.

### Fastfile

desc "Validate repo test1"
lane :validate_repo do
  lint_source
  execute_tests
  validate_docs
  ensure_tool_name_formatting
  ensure_code_samples
  ensure_special_docs_code_samples
  ensure_code_snippets
  ensure_actions_config_items_formatting
end

desc "Validate repo test2"
lane :validate_repo do
  lint_source
  execute_tests
  validate_docs
  ensure_tool_name_formatting
  ensure_code_samples
  ensure_special_docs_code_samples
  ensure_code_snippets
  ensure_actions_config_items_formatting
end

desc "Validate repo test3"
lane :validate_repo do
  lint_source
  execute_tests
  validate_docs
  ensure_tool_name_formatting
  ensure_code_samples
  ensure_special_docs_code_samples
  ensure_code_snippets
  ensure_actions_config_items_formatting
end

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
with open('Fastfile', 'r') as f_orig, open('Fastfile_new', 'w') as f_new:
    skipping = False
    for line in f_orig:
        if 'Validate repo test2' in line:
            skipping = True
        if not skipping:
            f_new.write(line)
        if line[:3] == 'end':
            skipping = False
```

Comment: @mttpgn..Thank you! what does this line do "line[:3]" exactly

Comment: @rag4260 `line[:3]` is a slice index and means the first three characters of the line. Hence, every line gets checked whether the first three characters are 'end'. Search for "slice" on this page for more details: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html

Comment: i get an extra line after removing the lines upto string “end”...how can we remove that line

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are many solutions, but I think the follow codes can solve your problem too.

```
need_delete = False
with open(path_to_old_file, 'r') as fin, open(path_to_new_file, 'w+') as fout :
    for line in fin:
        if line.endswith('"Validate repo test2"\n'):
            need_delete = True
        if need_delete and not line.strip():
            need_delete = False
            continue
        if not need_delete:
            fout.write(line)
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: i get an empty line after removing the lines upto string “end”...how can we remove that line.. i tired using readline() inside if block where we are checking for string “end” but it did not work out

Comment: So you want to delete to the empty line. Replace "line == 'end\n'" with "not line.strip()" will make it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to this, so I'm not sure how to credit the author, but this was useful to me:
[Regex Match all characters between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109882/regex-match-all-characters-between-two-strings)
Thanks @zx81

You can use the regex:

```
(?s)(?<="Validate repo test[\d]*").*(?=end)
```

http://www.rexegg.com/regex-modifiers.html#dotall
The first section will enable "dot all mode", the rest of the regex says "Selects all characters between ""Validate repo test[\d]*"" and "end"".
From there you can use regex sub to remove all of them. All together it would look a bit like this:

```
import re

fileText = file.read()
regex = re.compile(r"\"Validate repo test[\d]*\"", re.DOTALL)
result = re.sub(regex, "", fileText)

file.write(result)
```

Comment: Sure thing, regex is a great tool to get learning :) super useful