# get two ip separately

Tags: regex

my log files got two ip src-ip:132.23.35.1, dest-ip:10.23.56.1.

I 'm using regex:

```
\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}
```

it gets two IPs, if I want to retrieve IP address of src-ip (in this case, `132.23.35.1`) how to do?

I expect to get ip of source-ip and dest-ip separately.

Comment: Can you add an example of the log file you are reading, and what the desired output should look like?

Comment: log file: src-ip:132.23.35.1 source port: 23 dest-ip: 10.23.56.1 dest-port: 6540 desired output:132.23.35.1

Comment: perhaps try to edit the original question to include that information, so that it is all in one place and can be formatted more easily

Comment: question edited as below: 
log file: src-ip:132.23.35.1 source port: 23 dest-ip: 10.23.56.1 dest-port: 6540 desired output:132.23.35.1, using regex \d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3} get both 132.23.35.1 and 10.23.56.1

Comment: you should use capture groups , also read about greedy vs non-greedy approach. that will help solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
(?<=src-ip:)(.*)(?=,)
```

Example output from regexr

[image: example regexr output]

The regex code has been adapted from: [Regex Match all characters between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109882/regex-match-all-characters-between-two-strings)

Comment: Hi, we have another log src-ip:   132.23.35.1       dest-ip:   10.23.56.1, there are a lot of spaces between 132.23.35.1 and dest-ip, if i apply (?=dest-ip), i get 132.23.35.1 plus a lot of spaces, how to remove those space and get only ip address, thanks

Comment: Yes, that is why in my example I used the comma to as the end character. Is there a comma in your text file or is it a typo in the question above? The code should work with a comma, but if you only have whitespace instead you could use /(?<=src-ip:)([\S]*)/g