# RE to extract middle of line with or without a particuar word on the end

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract a string in the middle of a line with or without a particular word on the end. For example, this line:

```
START - some words and not THIS
```

should return "some words and not" and likewise, the line:

```
START - some words and not
```

should also return the same string. I've tried using lookahead from examples I've found with alternation for EOL, but adding the alternation returns a string ending with THIS. Here is the python regex:

```
[^-]*- (.+(?= THIS|$))
```

Removing |$ works, except when the line ends without THIS. The data I'm parsing has a small number of entries missing "THIS", so I need to account for both. What's the correct pattern for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a lazy quantifier (`.+?`) as in

```
[^-]*- (.+?)(?:THIS|$)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/jQqFPO/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Please, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6110113/6299864).

Basing on your example the following regex `(?<=START - )(.*)(?=THIS)` will catch `some words and not`. 
Hope it will help!

Comment: In testing (using regex101.com), it doesn't handle the case where THIS is not found at the end of the line, i.e. it ends in "not"

Comment: @stickybun I just added an update that does exactly that.  Let me know if it is not what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this should do the trick:

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r"(?!THIS)([^-]*- .+)(THIS)?$")
>>> s1 = 'START - some words and not THIS'
>>> regex.match(s1).groups()
('START - some words and not ', 'THIS')
>>> s2 = 'START - some words and not '
>>> regex.match(s2).groups()
('START - some words and not ', None)
```

Comment: Not working for me. I've been using regex101.com to test, but going right to python I get:

>>> regex = re.compile(r"(?!THIS)([^-]*- .+)(THIS)?")
>>> s1 = 'START - some words and not THIS'
>>> s2 = 'START - some words and not'
>>> regex.match(s1).groups()[0]
'START - some words and not THIS'

Comment: @stickybun sorry, I forgot the `$` at the end.   It should work now.

Comment: Nada. Same result, at regex101 and in python.

Comment: @stickybun What result is that?  I just ran the above in terminal so I don't see how our results can differ.

Comment: Not in python 3.7. I can paste your code into a python session verbatim, and the groups for the regex.match(s1) produce: ('START - some words and not THIS', None)