# Lookahead & Lookbehind including markers?

Tags: regex

Is it possible to include the markers in a lookahead & lookbehind search?

Example:

```
str = "my cat is the best pet in the world"
re.findall('(?s)(?<=cat)(.*?)(?=pet)', str)
```

will return "is the best"
what I want is "cat is the best pet"

thanks!

Comment: Just remove them groupings and lookarounds, `re.findall('(?s)cat.*?pet', s)`

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/a/7504859/3832970

Comment: Please someone re-close this as a duplicate, there are a million more like this "match-string-between-two-strings" questions on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just search directly for `\bcat.*?pet\b` and forego with lookarounds:

```
str = "my cat is the best pet in the world"
m = re.findall(r'\bcat.*?pet\b', str)
print(m)
```

This prints:

```
['cat is the best pet']
```

Comment: You may also add word boundary after `cat` and before `pet`