# Getting text in a dialogue conversation in R

Tags: r, nlp

So I have some text data that looking something like this,

BUYER: [TEXT]

SELLER: [TEXT]

BUYER: [TEXT]

When exporting to a CSV everything is condensed into a paragraph essentially and will look more like this:

BUYER: [TEXT]. SELLER: [TEXT]. BUYER: [TEXT].

I wanted to know if there's a way I can only track the Buyer responses and disregard what the seller has to say, I've been using the tidy text library and trying regex commands but nothing seems to be taking me in the right direction

Comment: Can you share your data?

Answer (score 2):

**Test data**
Since there is no sample data provided, following is a test data. Lets say that the output from your code is

```
BUYER: [TEXT]. SELLER: [TEXT]. BUYER: [TEXT]
```

**Potential solution**
Using the solution available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109882/regex-match-all-characters-between-two-strings), a modified version is presented below.

```
library(stringr)
s <- "BUYER: [TEXT]. SELLER: [TEXT]. BUYER: [TEXT]"
buyerStrings <- str_extract_all(s, pattern = "(?=BUYER:).*?((?=SELLER)|$)")
```

**Extracted data:**

```
print(buyerStrings)

[[1]]
[1] "BUYER: [TEXT]. " "BUYER: [TEXT]"
```

*Note: This extracted data can then be transformed to your needs for exporting*