# Python get a paragraph from a text

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I'm new to Python and I'm still learning about regular expressions. I want to get a paragraph between two key words; something like this:

Beginning of the text

**Keyword1**

Paragraph content

**Keyword2**

End of the text

How could I do it? I've tried this:

```
(?i)Keyword1(.*?)((?i)Keyword2Variant1|(?i)Keyword2Variant2)
```

But it doesn't really work.

Comment: "doesn't really work." - how exactly?

Comment: Try this `[.*\w\s]*Keyword1[.*\w\s]*Keyword2[.*\w\s]*`

Comment: It returns a None

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex Match all characters between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109882/regex-match-all-characters-between-two-strings)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure the single dot also matches newlines: use the `re.DOTALL` flag.

Slightly modified from your (non-workable) example:

```
text = """
Keyword1

Paragraph content

Keyword2Variant2
"""

import re

pattern = 'Keyword1(.*?)(Keyword2Variant1|Keyword2Variant2)'
match = re.search(pattern, text, re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
print(match.group(1))
```

yields

```
Paragraph content
```

(two blank lines before and after, but the rendering makes them hardly visible.)