# Unable to fetch multiline line text with Regex

Tags: python, regex

I have scanned a PDF with Tika which contains the text in the following format, having multiple line breaks

```
Some non Interview text

interview with Mr.XYZ



Question: How are you?
Answer: I am fine.

Question: What do you do?
Answer: Nothing



Some non Interview text
```

How do I apply regex?I can match words and spaces but it is not going multiline. I tried the following regex:

https://regex101.com/r/sekUyT/1

What all I want is interview related text which starts with *interview with* and is considered end when the text does not contain any more *Question:* and *Answer:*

Comment: It work's fine ```re.search("interview with \s?\w+.\w+", text).group()```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you want to match everything starting from "interview with" and until the end? Something like `interview with[\s\S]*` should do the job.

Comment: @Sushanth I just tried the python code generated and it returned nothing

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed not the end, the interview will be considered _end_ if there is no more text like _question_ and _answer_ . And your Regex is not working, I tired on Regex101 site

Comment: So, what did you try to make your regex stop at either `question` or `answer`? See [Regex Match all characters between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109882/)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Right now I am stuck that it is not fetching multiline text after _interview with_.  So far could not figure out how to stop once it does not find `question` or `answer`.

Comment: I'm still not sure what exactly you're trying to achieve but maybe try something like `interview with.+(?:\s+Question:.+\s+Answer:.+)*`. Demo: https://regex101.com/r/jNVigs/1

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed It is menitoned that I want to fetch all text starts with _Interview with_ and ends when there is no more the word "Answer" in it.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed the Regex you replied is the one I was looking for.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed can you tell what 's wrong was I doing? what does it mean by `:?`?

Comment: @Volatil3 It's called a non-capturing group (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3512471/8967612)). You might also want to spend some time in the [Regex reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618/8967612) because the pattern that you used was very unrelated to the requirements that you (kind of) described and that's why people were confused. You'll find a lot of resources there. Good luck :)

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Thanks and JazakAllah but what do we use for line breaks? PDF could be messy and there could be unnecessary line breaks after _Mr.XYZ_. How can I make sure it covers both line break and non line break case because there could be a line break after _interview with_.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `re.findall` funtion to get all the occurances of a particular text.

```
match = re.findall('interview with \s*?\w+.\w+',text)
```

match is a list of occurences of the matched text, if you only want the names, use : `'interview with \s*?(\w+.\w+)'` as the search string.